# What does the "+=" operator do in Java?

Tags: java

Can you please help me understand what the following code means:

```
x += 0.1;
```

Comment: Looks like adding 0.1 to a variable named x..

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608721/what-is-the-difference-between-double-a-a-int-b-and-int-a-double-b

Answer (score 143, accepted):

The "common knowledge" of programming is that `x += y` is an equivalent shorthand notation of `x = x + y`. As long as `x` and `y` are of the same type (for example, both are `int`s), you may consider the two statements equivalent.

However, in Java, `x += y` *is not* identical to `x = x + y` in general.

If `x` and `y` are of different types, the behavior of the two statements differs due to the rules of the language. For example, let's have `x == 0` (int) and `y == 1.1` (double):

```
    int x = 0;
    x += 1.1;    // just fine; hidden cast, x == 1 after assignment
    x = x + 1.1; // won't compile! 'cannot convert from double to int'
```

`+=` performs an implicit cast, whereas for `+` you need to explicitly cast the second operand, otherwise you'd get a compiler error.

Quote from Joshua Bloch's *Java Puzzlers*:

> (...) compound assignment expressions automatically cast the result of
>   the computation they perform  to the type of the variable on their
>   left-hand side. If the type of the result is identical to the type of
>   the variable, the cast has no effect. If, however, the type of the
>   result is wider than that of the variable,  the  compound 
>   assignment  operator  performs  a  silent  narrowing  primitive
>   conversion [[JLS 5.1.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#25363)].

Comment: Additionally, if `x` is a more complicated expression (like array or field access) instead of a single variable, its component expressions are now only evaluated once instead of twice.

Comment: X – = Y + 1 means X- =(Y+1) means X= X-(Y+1)=X-Y-1, Correct? But, somewhere, it gives X – = Y + 1 means X= X- Y+1, it this, which one is correct? @jakub.g

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay The first. Where did you get the second idea from?

Comment: This answer is a bit hard to follow. It emphasizes that `x += y` is not identical to `x = x + y`, while it mostly is. Only in some rare use-cases it's not (and even then, it's mostly the same).

Comment: @anatolyg you're right. Originally I wrote this answer long time ago, among dozens of "it's identical to x = x + y". I reworded the answer to make it more digestible.

Answer (score 29):

- `x += y` is `x = x + y`
- `x -= y` is `x = x - y`
- `x *= y` is `x = x * y`
- `x /= y` is `x = x / y`
- `x %= y` is `x = x % y`
- `x ^= y` is `x = x ^ y`
- `x &= y` is `x = x & y`
- `x |= y` is `x = x | y`

and so on ...

Comment: how about  =+ ?  it compiles but does nothing

Comment: @kommradHomer `x =+ y` is equivalent to `x = y`.

Comment: @kommradHomer `x =+ y` is `x = 0 + y`

Answer (score 13):

It's one of the [assignment operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). It takes the value of `x`, adds 0.1 to it, and then stores the result of (x + 0.1) back into `x`.

So:

```
double x = 1.3;
x += 0.1;    // sets 'x' to 1.4
```

It's functionally identical to, but shorter than:

```
double x = 1.3;
x = x + 0.1;
```

NOTE: When doing floating-point math, things [don't always work the way you think they will](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/42980).

Answer (score 3):

`devtop += Math.pow(x[i] - mean, 2);` will add the result of the operation `Math.pow(x[i] - mean, 2)` to the `devtop` variable.

A more simple example:

```
int devtop = 2;
devtop += 3; // devtop now equals 5
```

Answer (score 2):

In java the default type of numbers like 2 or -2(without a fractional component) is int and unlike c# that's not an object and we can't do sth like 2.tostring as in c# and the default type of numbers like 2.5(with a fractional component) is double;
So if you write:

```
short s = 2;
s = s + 4;
```

you will get a compilation error that int cannot be cast into short also if you do sth like below:

```
float f = 4.6;
f = f + 4.3;
```

you will get two compilation errors for setting double '4.6' to a float variable at both lines and the error of first line is logical because float and double use different system of storing numbers and using one instead of another can cause data loss;
two examples mentioned can be changed like this:

```
s += 4
f += 4.3
```

which both have an implicit cast behind code and have no compile errors;
Another point worthy of consideration is numbers in the range of 'byte' data type are cached in java and thus numbers -128 to 127 are of type byte in java and so this code doesn't have any compile errors:

```
byte b = 127
```

but this one has an error indeed:

```
byte b = 128
```

because 128 is an int in java;
about long numbers we are recommended to use an L after the number for the matter of integer overflow like this:

```
long l = 2134324235234235L
```

in java we don't have operator overloading like c++ but += is overloaded only for String and not for the let's say StringBuilder or StringBuffer and we can use it instead of String 'concat' method but as we know String is immutable and that will make another object and will not change the same object as before :

```
String str = "Hello";
str += "World";
```

It's fine;

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the bytecode whenever you want to understand how java operators work. Here if you compile:

```
int x = 0;
x += 0.1;
```

the bytecode will be accessible with jdk command `javap -c [*.class]`:(you can refer to [Java bytecode instruction listings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) for more explanation about bytecode)

```
0: iconst_0 //  load the int value 0 onto the stack
1: istore_1 //  store int value into variable 1 (x)
2: iload_1 // load an int value from local variable 1 (x)
3: i2d // convert an int into a double (cast x to double)
4: ldc2_w        #2                  // double 0.1d -> push a constant value (0.1) from a constant pool onto the stack
7: dadd //  add two doubles (pops two doubles from stack, adds them, and pushes the answer onto stack)
8: d2i // convert a double to an int (pops a value from stack, casts it to int and pushes it onto stack)
9: istore_1 // store int value into variable 1 (x)
```

Now it is clear that java compiler promotes `x` to double and then adds it with `0.1`.
Finally it casts the answer to `integer` .
There is one interesting fact I found out that when you write:

```
byte b = 10;
b += 0.1;
```

compiler casts `b` to double, adds it with `0.1`, casts the result which is `double` to `integer`, and finally casts it to `byte` and that is because there is no instruction to cast `double` to `byte` directly.
You can check the bytecode if you doubt :)

Answer (score 1):

`devtop += Math.pow(x[i] - mean, 2);` adds `Math.pow(x[i] - mean, 2)` to `devtop`.

Answer (score 0):

It increases the value of the variable by the the value after `+=`.
For example:

```
float x = 0;
x += 0.1;
//x is now 0.1
x += 0.1;
//x is now 0.2
```

It's just a shorter version of:

```
x = x+0.1;
```