# How do you declare x and y so that x+=y gives a compilation error and x=x+y not?

Tags: java, operators, shorthand

I ran into this question in an interview and couldn't come up with a solution. I know the vice versa can be done as shown in [What does the "+=" operator do in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456462/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java)

So the question was like below.

```
..... x = .....;
..... y = .....;

x += y; //compile error
x = x + y; //works properly
```

Comment: Curiously, does java allow concatenation with the plus sign? I don't know java, but that seems like a possibility

Comment: @mazzzzz just tested that, doesn't seem to be the solution here. += works fine to concatenate two strings.

Comment: What a useless interview question.

Comment: @Jonathon Completely agree. Such details are fine if you're looking at working on a compiler or JVM implementation, but for a regular programmer this is the kind of thing you just look at the spec for and then forget.

Comment: @Jonathon: Like most interview questions... I was interviewed recently in a job, and the interview was a pair-programming test with actual code to write and design to discuss. What a relief from stupid questions!

Comment: @Jonathon - it depends on whether it's being asked to find out whether the interviewee knows the answer - which _would_ be useless.  But seeing how someone reacts to a stupid interview question, or seeing how they work out loud on such a problem, maybe with hints, to see whether they have any language-lawyering proficiency at all -- those are worth something.

Comment: "Let's see if he goes and asks the question on StackOverflow. If he does, then let's hire him, because that would be the right and appropriate behaviour while working on an actual project!"

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this code

```
Object x = 1;
String y = "";

x += y; //compile error
x = x + y; //works properly
```

not entirely sure why this works, but the compiler says

> The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, String

and I assume that for the second line, `toString` is called on the Object.

EDIT:

It makes sense as the `+=` operator is meaningless on a general Object. In my example I cast an int to an Object, but it only depends on `x` being of type Object:

```
Object x = new Object();
```

It only works if `x` is Object though, so I actually think it is more that String is a direct subclass of Object. This will fail for `x + y`:

```
Foo x = new Foo();
```

for other types that I have tried.

Comment: Thank you. I tried in Eclipse and it is as you said. But I realized that in NetBeans it just compiles without any errors. So, does it mean that it isn't a general issue of java but depends on compilers?

Comment: x+=y should compile if x is Object and y is String, see http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7058838

Comment: Yeah, it is compiler dependent, because the question is how can you cause a compiler error in this manner. The Java language itself might not allow this sort of thing to happen, but compilers might not implement the spec correctly. So it's not really a clear question, and pretty horrific interview question

Comment: It's one JAVA tricky question... Better call it magic question ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible.

```
X x = ...;
Y y = ...;

x += y;         //1
//equivalent to
x = (X) (x+y);  //2

x = x+y;        //3
```

Suppose the type of `x+y` is Z. #2 requires a casting conversion from Z to X; #3 requires an assignment conversion from Z to X. "casting conversions are more inclusive than assignment conversions"(1). Therefore, as long as #3 is legal, #2 is legal, and #1 is legal.

On the reverse side, it is possible that #1 is legal, but #3 is illegal, for example

```
    byte x = 0;
    int y  = 1;
    x+=y;     // ok, x=(byte)(x+y), cast int to byte is allowed.
    x = x+y;  // error, assign int to byte
```

This information is not useful whatsoever; it is a flaw of Java making such surprising differences.

(1) http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.5

Comment: It is possible, see the answer from @Craigy.

Answer (score 2):

```
int  i = 5;
String s = "a";
System.out.println(i+=s);  //Error
System.out.println(i+s);   // No error
```

Basically, works for Any object or any non-string primitive and String combination.

I wonder which company it was? :)

Comment: This isn't really equivalent because here they are being converted to Strings while they would be converted to an `int` in the second case with `i = i + s` which gives a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

This thing will not always give you compilation error

If you are doing smoething like this :

```
class A{
public static void main(String args[]){
    String x = "10";
    String y = "s";
    x += y;
    System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

It will work fine

even if you do

```
class A{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int x = 10;
    float y = 11.5F;
    x += y;
    System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

it will work properly.

But if you take x and y two different type of variables like :

```
class X{
 }
class A{
public static void main(String args[]){
    X x = new X();
    float y = 11.5F;
    x += y;
    System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

In such cases it will fail to compile.

*Even you can concatinate any int, float etc with String.

Comment: But in this case `x + y` will also fail and not just `x += y`.