# multiplication in java by using *=?

Tags: java, operator-keyword, multiplication

`(i += 1)` is equivalent to `i = i + 1`

is it possible to have something like above by using multiplication like:

`(i *= 1)` ,  `i = i * 1`

I have try it by declare as double but I keep get 0.0 value in my result?

Comment: You can use debugger to get the value of i just before multiplication and just after multiplication. Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First declare `double i = 1.0;` (or `int i = 1;` if no decimal values are needed.) It seems that you're multiplying by zero. Of course, then `i` times `1` will always be `1` unless you're modifying the value of `i` somewhere else.

Other than that, be aware that `i *= 1` is *almost* equivalent to `i = i * 1`. The devil is in the details, as the first form will perform an implicit conversion as per the Java Language Specification, section [§5.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456548/201359):

> compound assignment expressions automatically cast the result of the computation they perform to the type of the variable on their left-hand side. If the type of the result is identical to the type of the variable, the cast has no effect. If, however, the type of the result is wider than that of the variable, the compound assignment operator performs a silent narrowing primitive conversion

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're multiplying zero by one.

`0 * 1 = 0`

Comment: Then any solution that can do as the way like above

Comment: @cchua: Do you understand what the problem is?

Comment: ya I know because I declare the value as 0 so it keep multiply 0. So do you have any other way to do as this rather then just using the `*=`

Comment: @cchua Do *what*? If it's zero no matter what you multiply it by, or how, the result will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

If `i` has no assigned value (other than zero) before multiplying then it will be 0*1 equals 0.

Answer (score 1):

Its taking the default value of double, as you have declared it in the class scope...

Try this...

```
class Test implements TestInterface {


        public static void main(String[] args){
            double i = 1;
            System.out.println(i *= 1);
        }
     }
```