# When is "i += x" different from "i = i + x" in Python?

Tags: python, operators

I was told that `+=` can have different effects than the standard notation of `i = i +`. Is there a case in which `i += 1` would be different from `i = i + 1`?

Comment: `+=` acts like `extend()` in case of lists.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That's a pretty subtle distinction, considering that `i=[1,2,3];i=i+[4,5,6];i==[1,2,3,4,5,6]` is `True`. Many developers may not notice that `id(i)` changes for one operation, but not the other.

Comment: @kojiro -- While it's a subtle distinction, I think it is an important one.

Comment: @mgilson it is important, and so I felt it needed an explanation. :)

Comment: Related question regarding differences between the two in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7456548/245966

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does plus equals (+=) do in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/what-does-plus-equals-do-in-python)

Answer (score 350, accepted):

This depends entirely on the object `i`.

`+=` calls the [`__iadd__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) (if it exists -- falling back on `__add__` if it doesn't exist) whereas `+` calls the [`__add__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__)<sup>1</sup> or the [`__radd__` method in a few cases](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)<sup>2</sup>.

From an API perspective, `__iadd__` is supposed to be used for modifying mutable objects *in place* (returning the object which was mutated) whereas `__add__` should return a *new instance* of something.  For *immutable* objects, both methods return a new instance, but `__iadd__` will put the new instance in the current namespace with the same name that the old instance had.  This is why

```
i = 1
i += 1
```

seems to increment `i`.  In reality, you get a new integer and assign it "on top of" `i` -- losing one reference to the old integer.  In this case, `i += 1` is exactly the same as `i = i + 1`.  But, with most mutable objects, it's a different story:

As a concrete example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b += [1, 2, 3]
print(a)  # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
print(b)  # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

compared to:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b = b + [1, 2, 3]
print(a)  # [1, 2, 3]
print(b)  # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

notice how in the first example, since `b` and `a` reference the same object, when I use `+=` on `b`, it actually changes `b` (and `a` sees that change too -- After all, it's referencing the same list).  In the second case however, when I do `b = b + [1, 2, 3]`, this takes the list that `b` is referencing and concatenates it with a new list `[1, 2, 3]`.  It then stores the concatenated list in the current namespace as `b` -- With no regard for what `b` was the line before.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>In the expression `x + y`, if `x.__add__` isn't implemented or if `x.__add__(y)` returns `NotImplemented` **and** *`x` and `y` have different types*, then `x + y` tries to call [`y.__radd__(x)`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__).  So, in the case where you have</sup>

<sup>`foo_instance += bar_instance`</sup>

<sup>if `Foo` doesn't implement `__add__` or `__iadd__` then the result here is the same as</sup>

<sup>`foo_instance = bar_instance.__radd__(bar_instance, foo_instance)`</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>In the expression `foo_instance + bar_instance`, `bar_instance.__radd__` will be tried before `foo_instance.__add__` *if* the type of `bar_instance` is a subclass of the type of `foo_instance` (e.g. `issubclass(Bar, Foo)`).  The rationale for this is that `Bar` is in some sense a "higher-level" object than `Foo` so `Bar` should get the option of overriding `Foo`'s behavior.</sup>

Comment: Well, `+=` calls `__iadd__` _if it exists_, and falls back to adding and rebinding otherwise. That's why `i = 1; i += 1` works even though there's no `int.__iadd__`. But other than that minor nit, great explanations.

Comment: @abarnert -- I always assumed that `int.__iadd__` just called `__add__`.  I'm glad to have learned something new today :).

Comment: @abarnert -- I suppose maybe to be *complete*, `x + y` calls `y.__radd__(x)` if `x.__add__` doesn't exist (or returns `NotImplemented` and `x` and `y` are of different types)

Comment: If you really want to be completist, you'd have to mention that the "if it exists" bit goes through the usual getattr mechanisms, except for some quirks with classic classes, and for types implemented in the C API it instead looks for either `nb_inplace_add` or `sq_inplace_concat`, and those C API functions have stricter requirements than the Python dunder methods, and… But I don't think that's relevant to the answer. The main distinction is that `+=` tries to do an in-place add before falling back to acting like `+`, which I think you've already explained.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you're right ... Although I could just fall back on the stance that the C API isn't part of *python*.  It's part of *Cpython* :-P

Comment: To further complicate the comments discussion:  `x + y` tries `type(y).__radd__` *first* if `issubclass(type(y), type(x))`.

Comment: @wim -- Thanks for this comment, I've added an additional paragraph at the bottom...

Comment: What do you mean *["] on top of `i`... [."]*?

Comment: I mean that the new object is going to be assigned to the name `i` -- Whatever was there previously will be one step closer to being garbage collected.

Comment: @wim That doesn't seem quite right, either, since a class is considered a subclass of itself (I guess just like a set is a subset of itself and a string is a substring of itself) and doing `x + y` with equal types [tries `__add__` first](https://repl.it/repls/CompetentRuddyBlog#main.py).

Comment: @HeapOverflow It's odd that a class is considered subclass of itself, I don't understand the reasoning for that. I should qualify as strict subclass, of course. Your point also reveals a documentation bug in the note [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ror__).

Comment: Added https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/22257 for the docs bug.

Answer (score 68):

Under the covers, `i += 1` does something like this:

```
try:
    i = i.__iadd__(1)
except AttributeError:
    i = i.__add__(1)
```

While `i = i + 1` does something like this:

```
i = i.__add__(1)
```

This is a slight oversimplification, but you get the idea: Python gives types a way to handle `+=` specially, by creating an `__iadd__` method as well as an `__add__`.

The intention is that mutable types, like `list`, will mutate themselves in `__iadd__` (and then return `self`, unless you're doing something very tricky), while immutable types, like `int`, will just not implement it.

For example:

```
>>> l1 = []
>>> l2 = l1
>>> l1 += [3]
>>> l2
[3]
```

Because `l2` is the same object as `l1`, and you mutated `l1`, you also mutated `l2`.

But:

```
>>> l1 = []
>>> l2 = l1
>>> l1 = l1 + [3]
>>> l2
[]
```

Here, you didn't mutate `l1`; instead, you created a new list, `l1 + [3]`, and rebound the name `l1` to point at it, leaving `l2` pointing at the original list.

(In the `+=` version, you were also rebinding `l1`, it's just that in that case you were rebinding it to the same `list` it was already bound to, so you can usually ignore that part.)

Comment: does `__iadd__` actually call `__add__` in the event of an `AttributeError`?

Comment: Well, `i.__iadd__` doesn't call `__add__`; it's `i += 1` that calls `__add__`.

Comment: errr... Yeah, that's what I meant.  Interesting.  I didn't realize that was done automatically.

Comment: The first attempt is actually `i = i.__iadd__(1)` - `iadd` *can* modify the object in place, but doesn't have to, and so is expected to return the result in either case.

Comment: Note that this means that `operator.iadd` calls `__add__` on `AttributeError`, but it can't rebind the result… so `i=1; operator.iadd(i, 1)` returns 2 and leaves `i` set to `1`. Which is a bit confusing.

Comment: @lvc: You're right, but that makes it even more confusing. You can use even return something other than `self`. Let me see how to make that clear in the answer.

Comment: @JBernardo: Yes, `+=` always rebinds the variable, but `operator.iadd` does not. That's why the docs explicitly say "`a = iadd(a, b)` is equivalent to `a += b`, not `iadd(a, b)` is equivalent to `a += b`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example that directly compares `i += x` with `i = i + x`:

```
def foo(x):
  x = x + [42]

def bar(x):
  x += [42]

c = [27]
foo(c); # c is not changed
bar(c); # c is changed to [27, 42]
```