# Please help me in understanding the Python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to understand following python code as I'm new to it.

```
import random

howMany = random.randint(0,1000)
stats = {}
for i in range(howMany):
   value = random.randint(0,500)
   stats.setdefault(value,0)
   stats[value]+=1
for item in stats:
   if stats[item] > 1:
       print item
```

Here is what I have understood so far, my questions will follow afterwards:

1. `howMany` stores the random number generated between 0 & 1000 inclusive of both.
2. `stats = {}` declares an empty dictionary
3. `i` will run depending upon the value of `howMany`. For example if `howMany`
   was 2 so `i` will run for two times with values is `0` and `1`.
4. `value` variable stores random number between `0` & `500` inclusive of both
5. I didn't understand `stats.setdefault(value,0)`. For example, the `value` variable has value `4`, then `stats.setdefault(4,0)` means what?
6. What does `stats[value]+=1` do? The expanded form of `stats[value]+=1` is
   `stats[value] = value + 1`?
7. I understood the following paragraph:

   ```
   for item in stats:
      if stats[item] > 1:
          print item
   ```

   Those values are printed which are greater than `1` in the `stats` dictionary. Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't understand "stats.setdefault(value,0)". For example, the
>   "value" variable has value 4, then stats.setdefault(4,0) means what?

The `setdefault()` method of dictionaries returns a value, when the key passed in does not match.  `value` is the key being searched for, and `0` is the value to set and return when no key is found.

It is used to avoid the `KeyError` exception, and to set default values for keys that don't exist:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1}
>>> d['b']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'b'
>>> d.setdefault('b',2)
2
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

> What does "stats[value]+=1" does? Is the expanded form of
>   stats[value]+=1 is stats[value] = value + 1 ?

Not quite, it means `stats[value] = stats[value] + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

**5.**  [dict.setdefault(key, default)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) does this:

> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

So it makes sure all keys start with 0 as the associated value.

```
stats.setdefault(value, 0)
```

is therefore equivalent to

```
if value not in stats:
    stats[value] = 0
```

**6.** No. But these are equivalent (good catch, glglgl):

```
stats[value] += 1
stats[value] = stats[value] + 1
```

They result in two different method calls in `stats` (`__iadd__` vs. `__setitem__`), so for some objects they do differ, but here they're equivalent. See the excellent link in Ashwini's answer for examples of this.

**7.** This code prints out all values that occur more than once.

In python 2.7+, your code sample would be better written using the [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class:

```
import random
import collections

howMany = random.randint(0,1000)
stats = collections.Counter(random.randint(0, 500) for i in range(howMany))
for item in stats:
   if stats[item] > 1:
       print item
```

Comment: 6) No. `stats[value] = stats[value] + 1`, not `stats[value] = value + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

`stats.setdefault(value,0)` means if a key named `value` is present in `stats` then return its value otherwise create a new key named `value` and set it's value to `0` and then return 0.

```
>>> dic = {}
>>> dic.setdefault("foo",5)  #creates a new key "foo" with value 5 and returns 5
5
>>> dic
{'foo': 5}
>>> dic.setdefault("foo",10)  # "foo" is already present then simply return it's value
5
```

**help** on `dict.setdefault`:

```
>>> dict.setdefault?
String Form:<method 'setdefault' of 'dict' objects>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:  D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D
```

> What does stats[value]+=1 do?

`stats[value]+=1` is equivalent to `stats[value] = stats[value] +1`

Though `+=` can behave differently for different objects, for details read this:

[When is "i += x" different from "i = i + x" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python)

Comment: For immutable values, `a += b` is indeed equivalent to `a = a + b`, but for *mutable* values that is not necessarily true. For a list `a`, `a += b` means `a.extend(b)` for example. In-place operations can behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

`stats.setdefault(value,0)` will set the default value for `stats[value]` to `0`. That is, the value `0` is associated with the key `value` only if it doesn't have a value associated with it before. It effecitvley is the same as:

```
if not stats.has_key(value):
    stats[value] = 0
```

This means that the **first** time `value` is seen, it will have a value of `0` associated with it.
This is important as you couldn't do the next step `stats[value]+=1` which expands to `stats[value] = stats[value]+1`, as it **requires** `stats[value]` to be defined, in this case it is defined as zero (if this is the first occurance of `value`, due to the `.setdefault(value,0)`). After which point it's incremented and the next time around, `stats.setdefault(value,0)` is redundant as it already has a value.

The following should make what `setdefault` does more obvious:

```
>>> d = {} #make a dictionary
>>> d.setdefault("key",100) #associate the value 100, with the key "key"
100
>>> d["key"] #see what is associated with "key"
100
>>> d["key"]+=100 #increment by 100
>>> d["key"] #test to see if incrementing worked
200
>>> d["notkey"]+=100 #demo to show what happens if we hadn't done defaultdict


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    d["notkey"]+=100
KeyError: 'notkey'

>>> d.setdefault("notkey",100) #set a default
100
>>> d["notkey"]+=100
>>> d["notkey"]
200
```

Answer (score 1):

5) from documentation:

> **`setdefault(key[, default])`**
>
> If key is in the dictionary, return its
>   value. If not, insert key with a value of `default` and return `default`.
>   `default` defaults to `None`.

6) Almost the same as `stats[value] = stats[value] + 1`

Operator `+=` performs an operation "in place" and in some cases can modify an existing object. Also, these operators may be different behavior, since it is determined by different methods [`__add__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) and [`__iadd__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__). However, in most cases you should not be concerned, because if  method `__iadd__` is not explicitly overridden, the augmented assignment falls back to the method `__add__`.

Example of different behavior:

```
>>> y = x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x + [4, 5]   # create *new* list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3]        # old list is not modified

>>> y = x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x += [4, 5]  # the operation is performed "in place", new object is not created
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # value of list changes
```

Comment: You may want to explain why, for point 6, `+=` is almost the same thing. You are right, but your explanation just creates more questions. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, just added explanation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, added an example of different behavior. I think so much more clearly.