# Assignment rules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've noticed a (seemingly) strange behaviour with assignments, which has led me several times to do programming mistakes.

See the following example first :

```
>>> i = 0
>>> t = (i,)
>>> t
(0,)
>>> i += 1
>>> t
(0,)
```

As expected, the value of the unique element of `t` does not change, even after the value of `i` has been incremented.

See now the following :

```
>>> l = [0]
>>> t = (l,)
>>> t
([0],)
>>> l[0] += 1
>>> t
([1],)  # <- ?
```

I don't understand why the initial zero in `t` is now one ; if I had incremented it with a reference to `t`...

```
>>> t[0][0] += 1
```

... I'd understand that it's value has changed, but this is not the case in the preceding example, where only `l` is explicitly referenced when incrementing.

I've got two questions:

1. Why is it so?
2. Are there special rules I should be aware of concerning this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because integers are immutable and lists are mutable.

```
>>> i = 0
>>> t = (i,)
>>> t[0] is i  # both of them point to the same immutable object
True
>>> i += 1  # We can't modify an immutable object, changing `i` simply 
            # makes it point to a new object 2.
            # All other references to the original object(0) are still intact.
>>> i
1
>>> t       # t still points to the same 0
(0,)
>>> x = y = 1
>>> id(x),id(y)
(137793280, 137793280)
>>> x += 1
>>> id(x),id(y)       #y still points to the same object
(137793296, 137793280)
```

for lists:

```
>>> l = [0]
>>> t = (l,)       
>>> t[0] is l #both t[0] and l point to the same object [0]
True
>>> l[0] += 1 # modify [0] in-place
>>> t
([1],)
>>> l
[1]
#another exmple
>>> x = y =[]    # x, y point to the same object
>>> x.append(1)  # list.append modifies the list in-place
>>> x, y          
([1], [1]) 
>>> x = x + [2]  # only changes x, x now points to a new object
>>> x, y
([1, 2], [1])
```

Comment: So, the thing one should be aware of is if he's dealing with mutable objects (lists, set, etc.) or immutable objects (strings, integers, tuple...) ?

Comment: There's also the fact that tuples are immutable; if the object stored in the tuple was a mutable one but it did not implement `__iadd__`, the operation would still not work; however, with a custom `__iadd__` method (which modifies `self`) it does.

Comment: @doukremt You can modify an mutable object from any of it's references(in-place operations only, `append`, `extend`, `+=`), while modifying a immutable object always returns a new object and all other references still point to the old object.

Comment: In my opinion, the examples are fine; anyway, mentioning mutable/immutable does confuse the mental picture of what happens. (It was not me who downvoted.) Any assignment simply means copying a reference. Any Python variable is a string as a key and the reference value bound to the key.

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, `t` (the tuple) holds a reference to `l` (the list).  When you do `l[0] += 1`, you're changing the list, but the tuple still holds a reference to the list.  In the first example, when you do `i += 1`, you're actually creating a *new integer* which your tuple doesn't hold a reference to.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python/15376520#15376520) that I wrote a while back for a much more in-depth explanation of the `+=` operator and how it is actually implemented.

Comment: Big +1 for the explanation of the difference between `+=` and `= ... +`