# semantics of generating symmetric matrices in numpy

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, symmetric

I tried to make a random symmetric matrix to test my program.  I don't care about the data at all as long as it is symmetric (sufficient randomness is no concern at all).

My first attempt was this:

```
x=np.random.random((100,100))
x+=x.T
```

However, `np.all(x==x.T)` returns False.  `print x==x.T` yields

```
array([[ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False],
   [ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False],
   [ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False],
   ..., 
   [False, False, False, ...,  True,  True,  True],
   [False, False, False, ...,  True,  True,  True],
   [False, False, False, ...,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

I tried to run a small test example with n=10 to see what was going on, but that example works just as you would expect it to.

If I do it like this instead:

```
x=np.random.random((100,100))
x=x+x.T
```

then it works just fine.

What's going on here?  Aren't these statements semantically equivalent?  What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those statements aren't semantically equivalent.  `x.T` returns a *view* of the original array.  in the `+=` case, you're actually changing the values of `x` as you iterate over it (which changes the values of `x.T`).

Think of it this way ... When your algorithm gets to index `(3,4)`, it looks something like  this in pseudocode:

```
x[3,4] = x[3,4] + x[4,3]
```

now, when your iteration gets to `(4,3)`, you do

```
x[4,3] = x[4,3] + x[3,4]
```

but, `x[3,4]` is not what it was when you started iterating.

---

In the second case, you actually create a new (empty) array and change the elements in the empty array (never writing to `x`).  So the pseudocode looks something like:

```
y[3,4] = x[3,4] + x[4,3]
```

and

```
y[4,3] = x[4,3] + x[3,4]
```

which obviously will give you a symmetric matrix (`y`.

Comment: That makes sense.  But it seems like a poor choice of semantics that `x+=<exp>` would ever be different than `x=x+<exp>`.

Comment: @aestrivex, `x += <exp>` would work as long as `exp` did not read the memory location that was being written to by `x +=` part.  It is the same reason why `memmove()` exists in C (and `memcpy()` has undefined behavior when memory regions overlap).

If you still want to use `+=`, you can do `x += x.T.copy()`.

Comment: @aestrivex -- Actually, my [highest upvoted question of all time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python/15376520#15376520) is explaining the difference between `x += something` and `x = x + something`.

Comment: Huh, interesting.  I had never heard of `__iadd__` before.  Thanks!