# Combining elements in list: seems like python treats the same item in two different ways and I don't know why

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm working my way through CodeAcademy and I have a question that's going unanswered there. The assignment is to take a list of lists and make a single list of all its elements. The code immediately below is my answer that worked. But what I don't understand is why "item" is treated as elements in a list for that code whereas (see comment continued below)...

```
m = [1, 2, 3]
n = [4, 5, 6]
o = [7, 8, 9]

def join_lists(*args):
    new_list = []
    for item in args:        
        new_list += item
    return new_list


print join_lists(m, n, o)
```

...the "item" in the code below is treated as the whole list instead of elements in a list. The code below gives the ouput:

```
 [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I also tried to use: **new_list.append(item[0:][0:])** thinking it would iterate through the index and sub-index but it gave the same result. I just don't understand how this is being interpreted.

```
m = [1, 2, 3]
n = [4, 5, 6]
o = [7, 8, 9]


def join_lists(*args):
    new_list = []
    for item in args:        
        new_list.append(item)
    return new_list


print join_lists(m, n, o)
```

Also, I know I could add another for-loop to the code above, and I get why that works, but I still don't understand with one line of difference why Python interprets these differently.

Comment: `+=` behaves like `list.extend`  for lists : [When is “i += x” different from “i = i + x” in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python)

Comment: @tdelaney oops! wrote that by mistake, wanted to write `list.extend` only.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary - I figured it was a typo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `+=` in-place add operator on a list does the same thing as calling [`list.extend()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) on `new_list`. `.extend()` takes an iterable and adds each and every element to the list.

`list.append()` on the other hand, adds a *single* item to the list.

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.extend([1, 2, 3])
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3]
>>> lst.append([1, 2, 3])
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I get that. I thought it was defined in the "for item in args." But the command determines how the item gets handled. Thanks so much!

Comment: @user1252778: Your `args` is a list of lists; each element in it is itself a list (taken from `m`, `n` and `o` passed to the function).

Answer (score 2):

Martijn (as always) has explained this well. However, the (for reference only) Pythonic approach would be:

```
def join_lists(*args):
    from itertools import chain
    return list(chain.from_iterable(args))
```

Comment: +1 Alternatively, how about `sum(args, [])`?