# difference between adding lists in python with + and +=

Tags: python, list

I've noticed when experimenting with lists that  `p= p+i` is different then `p +=  i` 
For example:

```
test = [0, 1, 2, 3,]
p = test
test1 = [8]
p = p + test1
print test
```

In the above code `test` prints out to the original value of `[0, 1, 2, 3,]`

But if I switch `p = p + test1` with `p += test1` As  in the following

```
test = [0, 1, 2, 3,]
p = test
test1 = [8]

p += test1

print test
```

`test` now equals `[0, 1, 2, 3, 8]`

What is the reason for the different value?

Comment: Here is an in depth answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/what-does-plus-equals-do-in-python

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4773111/2314737 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2027311/2314737

Comment: See also [Combining elements in list: seems like python treats the same item in two different ways and I don't know why](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17240162) and [When is "i += x" different from "i = i + x" in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15376509)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`p = p + test1` assigns a new value to variable `p`, while `p += test1` *extends* the list stored in variable `p`. And since the list in `p` is the same list as in `test`, appending to `p` also appends to `test`, while assigning a new value to the variable `p` does not change the value assigned to `test` in any way.

Answer (score 1):

tobias_k explained it already.

In short, using + instead of += changes the object directly and not the reference that's pointing towards it.

To quote it from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2347272/1076075) linked above:

> When doing foo += something you're modifying the list foo in place,
>   thus you don't change the reference that the name foo points to, but
>   you're changing the list object directly. With foo = foo + something,
>   you're actually creating a new list.

Here is an example where this happens:

```
>>> alist = [1,2]
>>> id(alist)
4498187832
>>> alist.append(3)
>>> id(alist)
4498187832
>>> alist += [4]
>>> id(alist)
4498187832
>>> alist = alist + [5]
>>> id(alist)
4498295984
```

In your case, test got changed since p was a reference to test.

```
>>> test = [1,2,3,4,]
>>> p = test
>>> id(test)
4498187832
>>> id(p)
4498187832
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` and `+=` represent two different operators, respectively `add` and `iadd`

From [http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**iadd**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__): the methods **iadd**(self,other), etc

> These methods are called to implement the augmented arithmetic
>   assignments (+=, -=, *=, /=, //=, %=, **=, <<=, >>=, &=, ^=, |=).
>   These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying
>   self) and return the result

`p += test1` uses the `iadd` operator and hence changes the value of `p` while `p = p + test1` uses the `add` which does not modify any of the two operands.