# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, why it's happening

Tags: python, int, iterable-unpacking

Here is three examples actually.

```
>>> result = []
>>> for k in range(10):
>>>    result += k*k

>>> result = []
>>> for k in range(10):
>>>    result.append(k*k)

>>> result = [k*k for k in range(10)]
```

First one makes a error. Error prints like below

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

However, second and third one works well.

I could not understand the difference between those three statements.

Comment: Related : [When is “i += x” different from “i = i + x” in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In-place addition on a list object extends the list with the elements of the iterable. `k*k` isn't an iterable, so you can't really "add" it to a list.

You need to make `k*k` an iterable:

```
result += [k*k]
```

Answer (score 4):

`result` is a list object (with no entries, initially).

The `+=` operator on a list is basically the same as calling its `extend` method on whatever is on the right hand side.  (There are some subtle differences, not relevant here, but see the [python2 programming FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html?highlight=__iadd__#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works) for details.)  The `extend` method for a list tries to iterate over the (single) argument, and `int` is not iterable.

(Meanwhile, of course, the `append` method just adds its (single) argument, so that works fine.  The list comprehension is quite different internally, and is the most efficient method as the list-building is done with much less internal fussing-about.)

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over an integer rather than a string or sequence.
For `result += k*k`,only if k was a string/sequence input,then it would be true but if k is a number, result would be a continued summation.
For `result.append(k*k)`,whether k is a string or number,result gets sequentially additions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too old but for anyone who lands here, this is a simple reproducible example to illustrate ''int' object is not iterable' error.

```
        lst1 =[3,4,5,6]
        def square(lst1):
            lst2  = []
            for num in lst1:
                lst2.append(num**2)
            return lst2
        #print(list(map(square,lst1))) # this will raise ''int' object is not iterable'
        print(list(map(square,list(lst1))))  # here making lst1 as list of list fixs the iterable problem i.e lst1 =[[3,4,5,6]]
```