# Difference between BINARY_ADD and INPLACE_ADD

Tags: python

I was going through the dis package of python. I tried code to see how it is working

```
>>> def get():
...     x=4
...     y=x+3 ............ this line
...     z=8
...     return y
```

and then run `dis.dis(get)` which prints the byte-code instruction for above code.

for `x+3` byte-code instruction is `BINARY_ADD` and when went trough package docs, I found another term `INPLACE_ADD`

Although in there they have mentioned what is `INPLACE_ADD` but I did not get the difference.

I have two question

a). what is difference between `BINARY_ADD` and `INPLACE_ADD`

b). how can I write code so that byte-code instruction shows `INPLACE_ADD`

Comment: `+=` is called in-place add. possible duplicate of [When is "i += x" different from "i = i + x" in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`INPLACE_ADD` is the `+=` operator:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> def f():
...     x += y
...     
>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (y)
              6 INPLACE_ADD         
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: is INPLACE_ADD any advantage over BINARY_ADD ?

Comment: @naveenyadav: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python

Answer (score 0):

you can see this website,get your answer
https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3.7/library/dis.html
for INPLACE_ADD must fast than BINARY_ADD,because INPLACE_ADD use "就地操作",this can small memory use and fast set result value.