# Python: Nested functions and variable scope

Tags: python, nested

This code doesn't work:

```
def lol():
    i = 1
    def _lol():
        i += 1
    _lol()
lol()
```

Error:

```
local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

But, the following code works fine:

```
def lol():
    i = [1]
    def _lol():
        i[0] += 1
    _lol()
lol()
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python scopes fit into 3 categories -- `local`, `nonlocal` and `global`.  By default, a function can only change a *reference* in the local scope (references are created with the assignment operator).

You're free to *mutate* an object that you have a reference to which is why the second example works (`i` is a reference to the list `[1]`, then you change/mutate it's first item).  In short, you're *mutating* the object that `i` references, you're not trying to change the reference.  Note that you can give a function access to change the reference in the global scope via the `global` keyword:

```
i = 1
def func():
  global i  # If you comment this out, i doesn't get changed in the global scope
  i = 2

func()
print(i)  # 2 -- 1 if the global statement is commented out.
```

Note that python3.x adds the `nonlocal` keyword.  It does the same thing as `global` but to the non-local scope.  e.g.

```
def foo():
    i = 1  # nonlocal to bar
    def bar():
        nonlocal i 
        print(i)
        i += 1
    return bar

bar1 = foo()
bar1()  # 1
bar1()  # 2
bar1()  # 3

bar2 = foo()
bar2()  # 1
bar2()  # 2

bar1()  # 4  bar2 doesn't influence bar1 at all.
```

---

## augmented operators

This is a bit more advanced, but provided to hopefully help answer questions regarding operators like `+=`.  Consider the case:

```
x = []
def func():
    x += [1]
```

You might expect this to work -- After all, `x += [1]` for a list `x` is really just `x.extend([1])`, *right?*.  Unfortunately, it's not quite.  We can disassemble `func` using `dis.dis` to see a little more what's going on.

```
>>> dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 BUILD_LIST               1
              9 INPLACE_ADD         
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (x)       ### IMPORTANT!
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice the byte-code instruction [`STORE_FAST`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_FAST)?  That basically says, store the result of [`INPLACE_ADD`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-INPLACE_ADD) in the name `x` in the local dictionary.  In other words, you write:

```
x += [1]
```

but python executes<sup>1</sup>:

```
x = x.__iadd__([1])
```

Why?  `__iadd__` should operate in place so why does it need to rebind the name to `__iadd__`'s return value?  The rebinding part is the problem -- i.e., this code *would* work:

```
x = []
def func():
    x.__iadd__([1])
```

The answer is because python has immutable objects and `__iadd__` needs to work with them too.  Because of this, `__iadd__` can return an object other than "`self`".  This ends up being incredibly useful.  Consider `i = 1; i += 1`.  This invocation only works because `int.__iadd__` is allowed to return a new integer.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Discussing this in even more depth is actually my all-time most upvoted answer on StackOverflow and can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python/15376520#15376520)</sup>

Comment: Could you also cover this: `i=[]; def x(): i+=[2]` - why doesn't that work? `+=` on lists doesn't reassign anything...

Comment: @georg -- Sure it does.  The assignment is just a little hidden.  If you disassemble that function using `dis`, you'll see a `STORE_FAST ... (i)` instruction.  `i += something` calls `i.__iadd__(something)` and stores the return value in the name `i` in the local scope.  if it didn't, `+=` wouldn't work for immutable objects (i.e. `int`).  Note that [`cls.__iadd__` should (but doesn't have to) return `self` for mutable objects and a new instance for immutable objects](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__).

Comment: Thanks )) I mean, don't you think this would be worth adding to your answer?

Comment: @georg -- I didn't want to complicate things too much, but . . . Hopefully I've made it clear that you don't need to look at that section unless you're actually interested . . .