# iteratively appending N items to list gives last item N times instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, append

I am accessing a list of dictionary items `list_of_dict = [{'ka':'1a', 'kb':'1b', 'kc':'1c'},{'ka':'2a'},{'ka':'3a', 'kb':'3b', 'kc':'3c'}]`, and trying to conditionally append each entry to another list `article_list` using a function `add_entries`.

**My desired output**

```
article_list = [{x:1a, y:1b, z:1c}, {x:2a}, {x:3a, y:3b, z:3c}]
```

**My code:**

```
def add_entries(list_of_dict):
   keys = ['x','y','z']
   #defining a temporary dictionary here
   my_dict = dict.fromkeys(keys,0)
   entry_keys = ['ka','kb','kc']

   my_list = []

   for item in list_of_dict:
    # conditionally append the entries into the temporary dictionary maintaining desired key names
        my_dict.update({a: item[b] for a,b in zip(keys, entry_keys) if b in item})
        my_list.append(my_dict)

   return my_list



if __name__ == "__main__":
   list_of_dict = [{'ka':'1a', 'kb':'1b', 'kc':'1c'},{'ka':'2a'},{'ka':'3a', 'kb':'3b', 'kc':'3c'}]
   article_list = []
   returned_list = add_entries(list_of_dict)
   article_list.extend(returned_list)
```

**My output**

```
article_list = [{x:3a, y:3b, z:3c}, {x:3a, y:3b, z:3c}, {x:3a, y:3b, z:3c}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Whats wrong**

`my_list.append(my_dict)` appends a **reference** to the `my_dict` object to `my_list`. Therefore, at the end of the `for` loop in your example, `my_list` is a list of references to the exact same dictionary in memory.

You can see this for yourself using the function `id`. `id`, at least in CPython, basically gives you the memory address of an object. If you do

```
article_list.extend(returned_list)
print([id(d) for d in article_list])
```

You'll get a list of identical memory addresses. On my machine I get

```
[139920570625792, 139920570625792, 139920570625792]
```

The consequence is that updating the dictionary affects 'all of the dictionaries' in your list. (quotes because really there are not multiple dictionaries in your list, just many times the exact same one). So in the end, only the last update operation is visible to you.

A good discussion on references and objects in Python can be found in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30340596/8791491

**The fix**

Moving the definition of `my_dict` inside the `for` loop, means that you get a new, separate dictionary for each element of `my_list`. Now, the update operation won't affect the other dictionaries in the list, and `my_list` is a list of references to several different dictionaries.

```
def add_entries(list_of_dict):
    keys = ['x','y','z']
    entry_keys = ['ka','kb','kc']

    my_list = []

    for item in list_of_dict:
        #defining a new dictionary here
        my_dict = dict.fromkeys(keys,0)

        # conditionally append the entries into the temporary dictionary maintaining desired key names
        my_dict.update({a: item[b] for a,b in zip(keys, entry_keys) if b in item})
        my_list.append(my_dict)

    return my_list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
keys=['x','y','z']
res=[{k1:d[k]} for d in list_of_dict for k,k1 in zip(d,keys)]
```

---

output

```
[{'x': '1a'},
 {'y': '1b'},
 {'z': '1c'},
 {'x': '2a'},
 {'x': '3a'},
 {'y': '3b'},
 {'z': '3c'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list_new_d=[]
for d in list_of_dict:
  new_d={}

  for k,v in d.items():
    if k == 'ka':
      new_d['x'] = v

    if k == 'kb':
      new_d['y'] = v

    if k == 'kc':
      new_d['z'] = v
  list_new_d.append(new_d)
```