# Why does python/numpy's += mutate the original array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

W = np.array([0,1,2])
W1 = W
W1 += np.array([2,3,4])
print W

W = np.array([0,1,2])
W1 = W
W1 = W1 + np.array([2,3,4])
print W
```

The upper code will mutate `W`, but the lower code will not mutate `W`. Why?

Answer (score 17):

This is true for almost any type of collection. This is simply due to the way python treats variables. `var1 += var2` is not the same as `var1 = var1 + var2` with collections. I'll explain it as far as I understand it, which can certainly be improved, so any edits/criticisms are welcomed.

```
print("1:")
x1 = [7]
y1 = x1
y1 += [3]
print("{} {}".format(x1, id(x1)))
print("{} {}".format(y1, id(y1)))

print("2:")
x2 = [7]
y2 = x2
y2 = y2 + [3]
print("{} {}".format(x2, id(x2)))
print("{} {}".format(y2, id(y2)))
```

Output:

```
1:
[7, 3] 40229784 # first id
[7, 3] 40229784 # same id
2:
[7]    40228744 # first id
[7, 3] 40230144 # new id
```

Saying `var1 = var1 + var2` creates a new object with a new ID. It takes the old value, adds it to the 2nd variable,  and assigns it to a new object with the NAME of the first object. In the `var1 += var2` example, it simply appends it to the object pointed at by the ID, which is the same as the old variable.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of

```
W = np.array([0,1,2])
W1 = W
W1 += np.array([2,3,4])
```

`W` points to some location in memory, holding a numpy array. `W1` points to the same location. `W1 += np.array([2,3,4])` takes that location in memory, and changes the contents.

In this case:

```
W = np.array([0,1,2])
W1 = W
W1 = W1 + np.array([2,3,4])
```

`W` and `W1` *start out* pointing to the same location in memory. You then create a new array (`W1 + np.array([2,3,4])`) which is in a new location in memory. (Keep in mind: the right hand side is always evaluated first, and only then is it assigned to the variable on the left hand side.) Then, you make `W1` point to this new location in memory (by assigning `W1` to this new array). `W` still points to the old location in memory. From this point on, `W` and `W1` are no longer the same array.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, `+` and `+=` are different methods that any class can implement. In numpy, `+=` is implemented to do in memory changes, while `+` returns a new array.

More details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python).

Answer (score 3):

In Python, the operator `+` (addition) redirects to either the `__add__` method of the left operand or the `__radd__` method of the right operand. We can ignore the latter case, since it is pretty rarely used (when addition does not commute).

The `+=` operator redirects to the `__iadd__` method, if one is defined. If `__iadd__` is not defined on the left operand, `a += b` becomes equivalent to `a = a + b`.

The thing to remember with `a += b` is that it is not just `a.__iadd__(b)` (or `type(a).__iadd__(a, b)`), it is `a = type(a).__iadd__(a, b)`. On the one hand, this forced assignment allows immutable types like `int` to define a meaningful `+=` operation. On the other hand, the following fails with a `TypeError` even though list addition happens in place:

```
tup = (['a'], ['b'])
tup[0] += ['c']
```

Numpy arrays are mutable objects that have clearly defined in place operations. If `a` and `b` are arrays of the same shape, `a += b` adds the two arrays together, using `a` as an output buffer. The function form of the operation is `a = np.ndarray.__iadd__(a, b)`, which modifies `a` and returns `a`.

Similarly, `a = a + b` is equivalent to `a = np.ndarray.__add__(a, b)`. Unlike `__iadd__`, however, `__add__` creates and returns a completely new array to hold the result, which is then assigned to `a`.

This has some additional implications for things like output type. If `a` has `dtype=int32` and `b` has `dtype=float64`, the in place operation will not change the type of `a`. Instead `b`'s values will be truncated. The result of `a + b` will have the wider type though, which would be `float64` in this example.

All the basic Python operators have equivalent function implementations in numpy. `a = a + b` is equivalent to `a = np.add(a, b)`. `a += b` is equivalent to `a = np.add(a, b, out=a)`.