# What does copy=False do in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In the documentation for the [PCA function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) in scikitlearn, there is a `copy` argument that is `True` by default.

The documentation says this about the argument:
`If False, data passed to fit are overwritten and running fit(X).transform(X) will not yield the expected results, use fit_transform(X) instead.`

I'm not sure what this is saying, however, because how would the function overwrite the input `X`? When you call `.fit(X)`, the function should just be calculating the PCA vectors and updating the internal state of the PCA object, right?
So even if you set copy to `False`, the `.fit(X)` function should still be returning the object self as it says in the documentation, so shouldn't `fit(X).transform(X)` still work?

So what is it copying when this argument is set to `False`?

Additionally, when would I want to set it to `False`?

Edit:
I ran the fit and transform function together and separately and got different results even though the copy parameter was the same for both.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(20).reshape((5,4))

print("Separate")
XT = X.copy()
pcaT = PCA(n_components=2, copy=True)
print("Original: ", XT)
results = pcaT.fit(XT).transform(XT)
print("New: ", XT)
print("Results: ", results)

print("\nCombined")
XF = X.copy()
pcaF = PCA(n_components=2, copy=True) 
print("Original: ", XF)
results = pcaF.fit_transform(XF)
print("New: ", XF)
print("Results: ", results)

########## Results
Separate
Original:  [[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19]]
New:  [[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19]]
Results:  [[  1.60000000e+01  -2.66453526e-15]
 [  8.00000000e+00  -1.33226763e-15]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -8.00000000e+00   1.33226763e-15]
 [ -1.60000000e+01   2.66453526e-15]]

Combined
Original:  [[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19]]
New:  [[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19]]
Results:  [[  1.60000000e+01   1.44100598e-15]
 [  8.00000000e+00  -4.80335326e-16]
 [ -0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -8.00000000e+00   4.80335326e-16]
 [ -1.60000000e+01   9.60670651e-16]]
```

Comment: I don't understand your question (though I'm not familiar with sklearn in particular). A call to `.fit(X)` has access to `X`, so there's nothing stopping that function call from mutating `X`. Are you familiar with how native python works in this regard?

Comment: Or is your point that `.fit` is a method of a `PCA` object but the mutation would affect the `X` array? Have you just tried calling `.fit(X)` with `copy=False` and printing it before/after the fit? Not copying the input data might be beneficial from a memory management standpoint, in case you know you won't need the original data afterwards.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I know what mutations normally are. I was confused since I didn't know why you would want to mutate the input X since that would change the dimensions of that matrix.

Comment: I also updated the question with results of the run, and now I'm more confused since the functions seem to produce different results.

Comment: The differences you see are on the order of machine precision; for all intents and purposes the results are the same. What would be interesting to check is the same with `copy=False` and `copy=True`. The suggestion of the documentation you're testing _should_ give the same result, and it does, so there's no question there.

Comment: Also, I don't think the _shape_ of `X` would change, but the _values_ inside could. As I said before: use `copy=False` and print `X` before and after a call to `.fit(X)` and see if anything happens. It's also possible that mutation of `X` is not guaranteed, only permitted.

Comment: Yeah, I tried True and False and they resulted in the same values, so maybe mutation of X is not guaranteed. But my question is still what could it be changed to?

Comment: My original answer was incorrect; see the revised version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example the value of `copy` ends up being ignored, as explained below. But here is what can happen if you set it to False:

```
X = np.arange(20).reshape((5,4)).astype(np.float64)
print(X)
pca = PCA(n_components=2, copy=False).fit(X)
print(X)
```

This prints the original X

```
[[  0.   1.   2.   3.]
 [  4.   5.   6.   7.]
 [  8.   9.  10.  11.]
 [ 12.  13.  14.  15.]
 [ 16.  17.  18.  19.]]
```

and then shows that X was mutated by `fit` method.

```
[[-8. -8. -8. -8.]
 [-4. -4. -4. -4.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4.]
 [ 8.  8.  8.  8.]]
```

The culprit is [this line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py#L414): `X -= self.mean_`, where [augmented assignment mutates the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910577/python-numpy-mutate-the-original-array).

If you set copy=True, which is the default value, then X is not mutated.

#### Copy is sometimes made even if copy=False

Why has not `copy` made a difference in your example? The only thing that the method  PCA.fit does with the value of `copy` is pass it to a utility function [`check_array`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L310) which is called to make sure the data matrix has datatype either float32 or float64. If the data type isn't one of those, type conversion happens, and that creates a copy anyway (in your example, there is conversion from int to float). This is why in my example above I made X a float array.

#### Tiny differences between `fit().transform()` and `fit_transform()`

You also asked why `fit(X).transform(X)` and `fit_transform(X)` return slightly different results. This has nothing to do with `copy` parameter. The difference is within the errors of double-precision arithmetics. And it comes from the following:

- `fit` performs the SVD as `X = U @ S @ V.T` (where @ means matrix multiplication) and stores V in the  `components_` property.
- `transform` multiplies the data by `V`
- `fit_transform` performs the same SVD as `fit` does, and then returns `U @ S`

Mathematically, `U @ S` is the same as `X @ V` because V is an orthogonal matrix. But the errors of floating-point arithmetic result in tiny differences.

It makes sense that `fit_transform` does `U @ S` instead of `X @ V`; it's a simpler and more accurate multiplication to perform because `S` is diagonal. The reason `fit` does not do the same is that only `V` is stored, and in any case it doesn't really know that the argument it got was the same that the model got to `fit`.