# Increasing an element in a numpy matrix also affects different matrix and unrelated rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to build two array so that every element is a 365-element array (separated in 30/31-element individual arrays) representing a calendar; the first array should contain the number of airplane flights that happen in a single day, and the second should contain the number of delayed flights in each day; every row in both arrays is supposed to contain such data for ONE specific Travel Agency.

I declared the arrays using the following code:

```
year = np.array([[0]*31,[0]*29,[0]*31,[0]*30,[0]*31,[0]*30,[0]*31,[0]*31,[0]*30,[0]*31,[0]*30,[0]*31,])
flights_1998_Carriers = np.array([year,]*14)
delays_1998_Carriers = np.array([year,]*14)
```

But whenever I increase the value of ONE specific day for a specific agency in one of the two arrays, the same day for EVERY agency in BOTH arrays is increased as well. For example:

```
print(flights_1998_Carriers[0][0][1])
print(delays_1998_Carriers[0][0][1])
flights_1998_Carriers[0][0][1] = flights_1998_Carriers[0][0][1] + 1
print(flights_1998_Carriers[0][0][1])
print(flights_1998_Carriers[1][0][1])
print(delays_1998_Carriers[0][0][1])
```

Would print the result:

```
0
0
1
1
1
```

I have tried everything I could think of but I can't understand WHY all the rows in both arrays are linked in such a way. Does anyone know where I'm messing this up? Thanks.

Comment: First I want to say, mutating either of the arrays this way is not just altering the other, it's actually mutating the `year` array. Maybe [this resource](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) will help, but I'm not actually super good with Python so my apologies if not.

Comment: Also! Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910577/why-do-python-numpy-mutate-the-original-array) is relevant?

Comment: Replacing "np.array([year,]*14)" with "np.array([copy.deepcopy(year),]*14)" DOES make is so modifying an array doesn't affect the other, but all the rows in the first arrays are STILL affected; I'm gonna keep trying to find a solution using copying functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [548]: year.shape                                                            
Out[548]: (12,)
In [549]: year.dtype                                                            
Out[549]: dtype('O')
In [550]: flights_1998_Carriers.shape                                           
Out[550]: (14, 12)
```

Also do a print of `year`.  You'll see it is an object dtype array of lists.

```
In [560]: flights_1998_Carriers.shape                                           
Out[560]: (14, 12)
```

Because of the `[year,]*14` construction, all elements in `flights_1998_Carriers[:,0]` reference the same list, which is also `year[0]`.  If you modify an element of `year[0]`, you'll see that change in `flights...` as well.  And `delays...` as well.

An object dtype array like `year` is essentially a list of lists, or a list of references to lists (stored else where in memory).  And when you make a new array with that list multiply syntax, you get the same duplicate issues that you would get with lists.

```
np.array([copy.deepcopy(year),]*14)
```

separates this array from `year`, but still replicates the references 14x.  You need to `copy` 14 times.

```
np.array([copy.deepcopy(year) for _ in range(14)])
```

Working with object arrays like this doesn't give much of an advantage over plain lists.  Operations might even be slower.  They certainly aren't fast like numeric numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. I guess I need to learn more about how python arrays are initialized and linked...