# Why do my_list *= 2 and my_list = my_list * 2 produce different results in a function that takes my_list as an argument?

Tags: python

Although both functions are logically doing the same thing i.e. doubling the list by itself, why does one function modify the original list and the other doesn't?
The only difference visible in the code is that `func2()` uses short-hand notation for doubling while `func1()` doesn't.

Aren't `my_list *= 2` and `my_list = my_list * 2` equivalent?

Approach 1:

```
def func1(my_list):
    my_list = my_list * 2

x = [1, 2, 3]
func1(x)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Approach 2:

```
def func2(my_list):
    my_list *= 2

x = [1, 2, 3]
func2(x)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: No, they are not equivalent. `*=` modifies the list in place. `*` returns a new list.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types - "`s *= n` **updates *s*** with  its contents repeated *n* times".

Comment: @johnrsharpe In python they have implemented using operator overloading ?

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh what do you mean? They're two different magic methods, `__mul__` and `__imul__`.

Comment: So when we do `my_list *= 2` it's basically a call to __imul__, which is achieved by overloading the operator `*=`, this I wanted to know.

Comment: Related for `+=`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58866870/3001761

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are Python in-place operator functions different than the standard operator functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772987/how-are-python-in-place-operator-functions-different-than-the-standard-operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) `*=` ([`__imul__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__imul__)) is only natively* available on mutable sequences, including `list` (emphasis mine):

| Operation | Result | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `s *= n` | **updates *s*** with its contents repeated *n* times | (6) |

whereas `*` ([`__mul__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mul__)) is available on [all sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

| Operation | Result | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `s * n` or `n * s` | equivalent to adding *s* to itself *n* times | (2)(7) |

For your two examples:

- `my_list = my_list * 2` is equivalent to `my_list = my_list + my_list`, which creates a *new*, longer list and assigns it back to the same name
- `my_list *= 2` is like `my_list.extend(my_list)`, it's an in-place operation

This is also mentioned in the data model documentation for [augmented assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__):

> These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying
> *self*) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, *self*).

These augmented assignment behaviours can be surprising, one's even called out in the [programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works).

** as [khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) points out in the comments, `*=` will fall back to using `__mul__` where `__imul__` isn't implemented, so for immutable sequences `foo *= bar` and `foo = foo * bar` do the same thing.*

Comment: `__imul__` may not be available on immutable sequences, but `*=` is. It falls back on  `__mul__`, so it has different behaviour.