# Why does copy of Pandas DataFrame Index maintain dependence?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

An issue appeared when concatenating two pandas DataFrames and proceeding the update the index.  After boiling down the issue we can ignore the concatenation.  Despite creating a copy of the new DataFrame or it's index, changing the elements of the copy still changes the original DataFrame index.  Below is a basic example you can run to create the issue.

A few alternates that have been tried:

1. `ind = df.copy().index.to_numpy()`: changing `ind` alters `df`
2. `ind = df.index.copy().to_numpy()`: changing `ind` alters `df`
3. `ind = df.copy(deep=True).index.to_numpy()`: changing `ind` alters `df`
4. `ind = df.index.copy(deep=True).to_numpy()`: changing `ind` **does not** alter `df`.

Why don't options 1-3 behave like option 4?

```py
import pandas as pd

# Define two data frames
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1.,2.], data={'y':[0,0,0]})
print('Original DataFrame')
print(df)

# Update index
ind = df.copy().index.to_numpy() # Option 1
#ind = df.index.copy().to_numpy() # Option 2
#ind = df.copy(deep=True).index.to_numpy() # Option 3
#ind = df.index.copy(deep=True).to_numpy() # Option 4
ind[:] += 3

# Why does the index of (df) get updated?
print("\n\nAfter updating copy of index:")
print(df)
```

Output (Pandas v1.0.1, Python v3.7.4):

```
Original DataFrame
     y
0.0  0
1.0  0
2.0  0


After updating copy of index:
     y
3.0  0
4.0  0
5.0  0
```

Comment: I have tried to explain how they are different with a brief explanation, hope that answers the question !

Comment: For reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910577/why-does-python-numpys-mutate-the-original-array. Perhaps use `ind = ind + 3` if for some reason you need to ensure changes don't propagate back to the df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is, the culprit is [`to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) (Emphasis mine):

> **copy**: ***bool, default False***
>   Whether to ensure that the returned value is a
>   not a view on another array. Note that `copy=False` does not ensure that
>   `to_numpy()` is no-copy. Rather, **`copy=True` ensure that a copy is made**,
>   even if not strictly necessary.

```
>>> ind = df.copy().index.to_numpy(copy=True)
>>> ind
array([0., 1., 2.])
>>> df
     y
0.0  0
1.0  0
2.0  0
>>> ind += 3
>>> df
     y
0.0  0
1.0  0
2.0  0
>>> ind
array([3., 4., 5.])
```

Since `to_numpy` uses [`np.asarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html), it's worthwhile to make note of this bit as well (Emphasis mine):

> **out** : ***ndarray***
>   Array interpretation of *a*. **No copy is performed** if the
>   input is already an `ndarray` with matching dtype and order. If *a* is a
>   subclass of `ndarray`, a base class `ndarray` is returned.

---

The deeper answer is: the underlying object reference of the `index` is carried over, unless a true copy is explicitly made on the `index`, *not* the `df` itself.  Observe this test:

```
tests = '''df.index
df.copy().index
df.index.copy()
df.copy(deep=True).index
df.index.copy(deep=True)'''

print('Underlying object reference test...')
for test in tests.split('\n'):

    # !!! Do as I say not as I do  !!!
    # !!! eval will ruin your life !!!

    print(f'{"{:54}".format(f"With {test} is:")}{eval(test).values.__array_interface__["data"]}')
    print(f'{"{:54}".format(f"With {test}.to_numpy() is:")}{eval(test).to_numpy().__array_interface__["data"]}')
    print(f'{"{:54}".format(f"With {test}.to_numpy(copy=True) is:")}{eval(test).to_numpy(copy=True).__array_interface__["data"]}')
```

Results:

```
Underlying object reference test...
With df.index is:                                     (61075440, False) # <-- reference to watch for
With df.index.to_numpy() is:                          (61075440, False) # same as df.index
With df.index.to_numpy(copy=True) is:                 (61075504, False) # True copy
With df.copy().index is:                              (61075440, False) # same as df.index
With df.copy().index.to_numpy() is:                   (61075440, False) # same as df.index
With df.copy().index.to_numpy(copy=True) is:          (61075504, False) # True copy
With df.index.copy() is:                              (61075440, False) # same as df.index
With df.index.copy().to_numpy() is:                   (61075440, False) # same as df.index
With df.index.copy().to_numpy(copy=True) is:          (61075504, False) # True copy
With df.copy(deep=True).index is:                     (61075440, False) # same as df.index
With df.copy(deep=True).index.to_numpy() is:          (61075440, False) # same as df.index
With df.copy(deep=True).index.to_numpy(copy=True) is: (61075504, False) # True copy
With df.index.copy(deep=True) is:                     (61075504, False) # True copy
With df.index.copy(deep=True).to_numpy() is:          (61075504, False) # True copy
With df.index.copy(deep=True).to_numpy(copy=True) is: (61075472, False) # True copy of True copy
```

As you can see, unless the explicit true copy is made on the `index` directly, or on the `to_numpy` method, you'll always inadvertently change your existing data.

As to why the True Copies have the same reference (except True copy of True copy), I don't have a full appreciation of what's happening under the hood.  But I'm *guessing* it has to do with some optimization magic to save memory.  That however, is probably for another question.

Comment: OP in case you already saw this, I updated the answer with a more exhaustive test for some sanity.  Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I think you could argue that the issue is really with the `+=` operator. Using `ind = ind + 3` gives a changed `ind` and an unchanged `df` regardless of which of the 4 methods you choose.

Comment: @ALollz Well yes, but no... because if the object reference wasn't carried over, modifying the object inplace wouldn't have mattered either way.  There could have been a use case for the `+=` that we don't know of.  I do see your point, but I think object reference is something that's kinda a "gotcha" for the unaware so I usually prefer to keep that mindful.

Comment: @r.ook This is helpful.  Would you agree that the culprit is not `to_numpy()`, however?  If a proper copy (i.e of both data and index or just index) was made in the previous chain of commands then `to_numpy()` won't need any explicit keyword arguments.  But what I'm reading from your answer is that adding the `copy=True` keyword argument to `to_numpy()` ensures a proper copy regardless of the earlier chain of commands.

Comment: As you mentioned @r.ook, perhaps this is for another question, but the level of details required to make a full copy of a dataframe seems unfriendly and maybe even considered a bug.  Maybe there is a deeper reason but from a user perspective the behavior is surprising.

Comment: Yeah, the test that `df.copy(deep=True).index` is still the same is a little surprising for me.  I actually dug further, and believe there's several component that leads to this.  The root is that you explicitly assigned an object to the `index=...` kwarg in the df constructor.  When not explicitly defined this issue is not observed.  The second is that you change the returned object of `to_numpy()`.  If you had done `df.copy().index +=1`, this would not be observed, at all.  `pd.Index` object probably have some built in to copy these underlying references when updating in place.

Comment: So I still think the main issue resides with `to_numpy()`, since it's the universal keypoint in your example that can guarantee a true copy.  Whether or not the underlying reference within the `index` is the same across copies become less important, because `pd.Index` handles that updating separately.  But as soon as you move it away into `numpy` it handles it differently.  e.g. `a1 = np.array([1,2,3]); a2= a1.copy(); a2+=1` would not impact `a1`.

Comment: Thanks @r.ook.  Good to know to think twice before using `to_numpy()`.  Had the example used `ind = np.array(df.copy().index)` the issue would not be observed.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between Deep and Shallow Copy:

In a Shallow Copy: `only the reference of the object gets copied, so any change to the original object or copied object causes a change to both objects.`

In a Deep Copy :`the entire object is copied along with the reference, hence any changes to either of the objects does not affect the other(i.e they are independent objects)`

Cases Provide :

The first one is shallow copy and in shallow copy the index gets altered, there is no guarantee of keeping the index intact :

`ind = df.copy().index.to_numpy(): changing ind alters df`

The second one copies the dataframe and the index but by default it copies shallow and not deep. Hence the index does not stay intact:

`ind = df.index.copy().to_numpy(): changing ind alters df`

The third one copies all the elements of the dataframe with a deep Copy but since it does not take into account the index, the index gets altered:

`ind = df.copy(deep=True).index.to_numpy(): changing ind alters df`

As for this last one, the index is part of the deep copy hence it is completely copied keeping index intact, so `df` has no relation with `ind` except that ind is a full copy of it and exists independently :

`ind = df.index.copy(deep=True).to_numpy(): changing ind does not alter df.`

In the above cases, when you make a shallow copy any change in either `df` or `ind` results in change of the index. But with deep copy along with the index you have 2 completely independent dataframes.

Comment: Documentation for [pandas.DataFrame.copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) shows that the default is a deep copy.  The documentation makes it sound like a deep copy will create a "copy of the object's indicies and data".  Does that conflict with the explanation of the first case?

Comment: It does conflict, because based on the behavior you mentioned it is a shallow copy. A deep copy will take into account the indices

Comment: could have something to do with `to_numpy()`

Comment: Thanks for kicking off the deeper discussion into deep/shallow copies of pandas dataframe and index.