# Slicing a NumPy array within a loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need a good explanation (reference) to explain NumPy slicing within (for) loops. I have three cases.

```
def example1(array):
    for row in array:
        row = row + 1
    return array

def example2(array):
    for row in array:
        row += 1
    return array

def example3(array):
    for row in array:
        row[:] = row + 1
    return array
```

A simple case:

```
ex1 = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
ex2 = ex1.copy()
ex3 = ex1.copy()
```

returns:

```
>>> example1(ex1)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

>>> example2(ex2)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

>>> example3(ex3)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

It can be seen that the first result differs from the second and third.

Comment: Related question, hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python/15376520#15376520

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## First example:

You extract a row and add 1 to it. Then you *redefine* the **pointer** `row` but not what the `array` contains! So it will not affect the original array.

## Second example:

You make an in-place operation - obviously this will affect the original array - as long as it is an array.

If you were doing a double loop it wouldn't work anymore:

```
def example4(array):
    for row in array:
        for column in row:
            column += 1
    return array

example4(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

this doesn't work because you don't call `np.ndarray`'s `__iadd__` (to modify the data the array points to) but the python `int`'s `__iadd__`. So this example only works because your rows are numpy arrays.

## Third example:

`row[:] = row + 1` this is interpreted as something like `row[0] = row[0]+1, row[1] = row[1]+1, ...` again this works in place so this affects the original array.

## Bottom Line

If you are operating on mutable objects, like `list`s or `np.ndarray` you need to be careful what you change. Such an object only **points** to where the actual data is stored in memory - so changing this **pointer** (`example1`) doesn't affect the saved data. You need to follow the pointer (either directly by `[:]` (`example3`) or indirectly with `array.__iadd__` (`example2`)) to change the saved data.

Answer (score 3):

In the first code, you don't do anything with the new computed row; you rebind the name `row`, and there is no connection to the array anymore.

In the second and the third, you dont rebind, but assign values to the old variable. With `+=` some internal function is called, which varies depending on the type of the object you let it act upon. See links below.

If you write `row + 1` on the right hand side, a new array is computed. In the first case, you tell python to give it the *name* `row` (and forget the original object which was called `row` before). And in the third, the new array is written to the slice of the old `row`.

For further reading follow the link of the comment to the question by @Thiru above. Or read about [assignment and rebinding in general...](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)