# Python strange behavior: "+=" creates aliases

Tags: python, alias

I can't explain the behavior of this code:

```
n=[[0,0],[0,0]]
m=n.copy()
for i in range(len(m)):
     m[i]+=[0]
```

The output I get is (not what I expected):

```
>>> m
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> n
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

If I type instead:

```
n=[[0,0],[0,0]]
m=n.copy()
for i in range(len(m)):
     m[i]=m[i]+[0]
```

I get the correct output (which is what I originally expected):

```
>>> m
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> n
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

So, it looks like if I use the "+=" shortcut the two matrices "m" and "n" become aliases. Can somebody please explain why this is happening?.

Comment: `n.copy()` is not a deep copy, both `m` and `n` contain the **same** list instances

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python/15376520

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here is that `some_list += some_iterable` is effectively the same thing as `some_list.extend(some_iterable)`.

`some_list = some_list + [something_else]` actually creates a new list out of `some_list` and `[something_else]` concatenated together and then assigns that new list back on the left hand side of the `=` operator.

When you think of it this way, and with the knowledge that after copying, `m[idx] is n[idx]` for all `0 <= idx < len(m)`<sup>1</sup>, it's easier to see why the `+=` version changes show up in both `m` and `n`.

<sup><sup>1</sup>`list.copy()` makes a **shallow** copy -- which means that it only copies references.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

`n.copy()` creates a shallow copy, so `n[i]` and `m[i]` are already pointing to the same object (although `m` and `n` are different).

For lists, `x += y` is not *quite* the same thing as `x = x + y` - the former mutates `x` directly (it's equivalent to `x.extend(y)`) while the latter assigns `x` to a new value.

These two facts combined explain the behaviour.