# Tuples: += operator throws exception, but succeeds?

Tags: python, tuples

Why does the following throw an exception, although it succeeds?

```
>>> t = ([1, 2, 3], 4)
>>> t[0] += [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> t
([1, 2, 3, 1], 4)
>>>
```

Comment: [Why does `a_tuple[i] += [‘item’]` raise an exception when the addition works](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works)

Answer (score 17):

Found the answer on IRC.

`t[0] += [1]` is several discrete actions:

1. loading `t[0]`
2. building a new list with `1` in it
3. adding that `[1]` to whatever `t[0]` is
4. reassigning `t[0]`

It seems that `x += y` is basically `x = x + y` (but, is it?)

The tricky bit is that `+=` implies assignment to both the tuple `t` and to the list `t[0]`

`t[0] += [1]` is not *literally* `t[0] = t[0] + [1]`, it is: `t[0] = t[0].__iadd__([1])`

What really happens is:

1. `__iadd__` both mutates the list and returns it. So the list (which is the first element in `t`) has already got `1` appended to it.
2. tuple's mutation is attempted in-place as well, but tuples are immutable, resulting in the exception.

Why is this not visible in plain sight? Because a n00b like me would expect `t[0] += [1]` to either succeed all together or fail, because it's one short line of python. But that's not always the case.

Comment: This is a good question and a good answer.  +1 from me.  Also, for more background on  `a += b` vs  `a = a + b`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python/15376520#15376520) (disclaimer -- I wrote one of the answers).

Answer (score 7):

It can also help to understand this behavior by taking a look at the bytecode with [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html).

```
In[5]: dis('t[0] += [1]')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (t)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              6 DUP_TOP_TWO
              7 BINARY_SUBSCR
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             11 BUILD_LIST               1
             14 INPLACE_ADD
             15 ROT_THREE
             16 STORE_SUBSCR
             17 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

- The value of `t[0]` is placed on top of the stack with `BINARY_SUBSCR`, which is a (mutable) list in this case.
- The value on the top of the stack has `+= [1]` performed on it with `INPLACE_ADD`, where in this case the top of the stack refers to the list inside the tuple.
- The assigning of `t[0]` to the top of the stack occurs with `STORE_SUBSCR`, which fails here as `t` itself is an immutable tuple, raising the error *after* the `+=` assignment has already occurred.

Answer (score 3):

The Python developers wrote an official explanation about why it happens here: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works

The short version is that += actually does two things, one right after the other:

1. Take the thing on the right and add it to the variable on the left
2. Put the result into the variable on the left

In this case, step 1 works because you’re allowed to add stuff to lists (they’re mutable), but step 2 fails because you can’t put stuff into tuples after creating them (tuples are immutable).

In a real program, I would suggest you don't do this because t[0].extend(['c']) does the exact same thing.