# How does python 3 print(list, list.pop())?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For print() with multiple arguments, I thought it evaluates them one by one. However, the following code

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(a, a[:], a.pop(), a, a[:])
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3, 4] 4 [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
```

I thought python would evaluate `a` first, then `a[:]`, then `a.pop()`, then `a` and `a[:]` again, which would print

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4] 4 [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
```

So how exactly does this work?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761707/what-is-the-order-of-evaluation-in-python-when-using-pop-list-1-and

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you call a function (any function). The **arguments are first evaluated left-to-right**. So your code is *equivalent* to:

```
arg1 = a
arg2 = a[:]
arg3 = a.pop()
arg4 = a[:]
print(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)
```

(of course the variables `arg1`, `arg2`, etc. do not exist at the Python level)

`arg1` will thus **refer to the same list as `a`**, next we make a **shallow copy of `a` and store it in `arg2`**, then we **pop from `a` and the last item is stored in `arg3`** and finally we make **another shallow copy** (of `a` at that point) and store it in `arg4`.

So that means that:

```
arg1 = a         # arg1 = a = [1,2,3,4]
arg2 = a[:]      # arg2 = [1,2,3,4]
arg3 = a.pop()   # arg1 = a = [1,2,3], arg3 = 4
arg4 = a[:]      # arg4 = [1,2,3]
print(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)
```

Next the `print(..)` statement is called with these argument and thus printed like we see in the comments. So it will print:

```
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3, 4] 4 [1, 2, 3]
```

The important part is thus that `a.pop()` will not only return the last element of the list referenced by both `a` and `arg1`, but also modify that list (remove the last element). So as a result `arg1` and `a` still refer to the same list, but it is modified.