# How to update list with function (with return value) in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am implementing few list methods manually like append(), insert(), etc. I was trying to add element at the end of list (like append method). This the working code i am using:

```
arr = [4,5,6]

def push(x, item): 
  x += [item]
  return x

push(arr,7)
print(arr)      #Output: [4,5,6,7]
```

But when I am implementing same code with little difference. I am getting different output.

```
arr = [4,5,6]

def push(x, item): 
  x = x + [item]
  return x

push(arr,7)
print(arr)      #Output: [4,5,6]
```

And I am facing same for insert method. Here is code for insert method:

```
arr = [4,5,7,8]

def insert(x, index, item): 
  x = x[:index] + [item] + x[index:]
  return x

insert(arr,2,6)
print(arr)      #Output: [4,5,7,8]
```

I know I can store return value to the list by `arr=insert(arr,2,6)` but I want an alternative solution, that list automatically gets update after calling function like in my first code sample.

**Edit 1:**
I think `x[index:index] = [item]`  is better solution for the problem.

Comment: [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign to a slice of the list to implement your `insert` w/o using `list.insert`:

```
def insert(x, index, item):
    x[:] = x[:index] + [item] + x[index:]
```

this replaces the contents of the object referenced by `x` with the new list. No need to then return it since it is performed in-place.

Comment: Why not just use `x[index:index] = [item]`? That avoids at least some temporary copies :)

Answer (score 3):

`x += [item]` and `x = x + [item]` are not a little difference.  In the first case, you are asking to make a change to the list referenced by `x`; this is why the result reflects the change.  In the second, you are asking to have `x` reference a new list, the one made by combining `x`'s original value and `[item]`.  Note that this does *not* change `x`, which is why your result is unchanged.

Also note that your return statements are irrelevant, since the values being returned are ignored.

Comment: This was so straight-forward, and allows for doing everything you might want to the original argument.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example you ***mutated***(a.k.a changed) the list object referred to by `x`. When Python sees `x += [item]` it translates it to:

```
x.__iadd__([item])
```

As you can see, we are mutating the list object referred to by `x` by calling it's overloaded in-place operator function `__iadd__`. As already said, `__iadd__()` mutates the existing list object:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2]
>>> lst.__iadd__([3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

In your second example, you asked Python to assign `x` to a new reference. The referenced now referrer to a new list object made by combining (not mutating) the `x` and `[item]` lists. Thus, `x` was never changed.

When Python sees `x = x + [item]` it can be translated to:

```
x = x.__add__([item])
```

The `__add__` function of lists *does not* mutate the existing list object. Rather, it returns a new-list made by combing the value of the existing list and the argument passed into `__add__()`:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2]
>>> lst.__add__([3]) # lst is not changed. A new list is returned.
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

You need to return the the result of the version of `push` to the `arr` list. The same goes for `insert`.

Comment: This is nice info. I wish my Python classes didn't tell me that `x += 1` and `x = x + 1` are the same....since apparently they are not.

Comment: Yeah @dwllama, functionally I suppose they are the same. But as the OP saw here, there are issues you can run into when you take this functional equivalence to far.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you haven't captured the result you return.  Some operations (such as `+=`) modify the original list in place; others (such as `x = x + item`) evaluate a new list and reassign the local variable `x`.

In particular, note that `x` is not *bound* to `arr`; `x` is merely a local variable.  To get the returned value into `arr`, you have to assign it:

```
arr = push(arr, 7)
```

or

```
arr = insert(arr, 2, 6)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class DerivedList(list):
    def insertAtLastLocation(self,obj):
        self.__iadd__([obj])        

parameter=[1,1,1]
lst=DerivedList(parameter)
print(lst)   #output[1,1,1]
lst.insertAtLastLocation(5)
print(lst)   #output[1,1,1,5]
lst.insertAtLastLocation(6)
print(lst)   #output[1,1,1,5,6]
```

You can use this code to add one element at last position of list

```
class DerivedList(list):
    def insertAtLastLocation(self,*obj):
        self.__iadd__([*obj])

parameter=[1,1,1]
lst=DerivedList(parameter)
print(lst)    #output[1,1,1]
lst.insertAtLastLocation(5)
print(lst)     #output[1,1,1,5]
lst.insertAtLastLocation(6,7)
print(lst)    #output[1,1,1,5,6,7]
lst.insertAtLastLocation(6,7,8,9,10)
print(lst)   #output[1,1,1,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

This code can add multiple items at last location