# what does '**+' operator behave in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I am a newbie for python and trying to understand the below piece.

```
[i**+1 for i in range(3)]
```

I know that `i += 1` means `i = i + 1` but what does `**+` mean?
I know `**` means exponent but the output of the above list comprehension puzzling me.

Comment: [Sometimes “i += x” is different from “i = i + x” in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15376509/8881141)

Comment: @Piinthesky this question is not really relevant. The `+` here is a unary operator.

Comment: @DeepSpace Not for the list comprehension and not for the example given, but why not point out that this assumed equivalence is sometimes a misconception?

Answer (score 5):

This confusion is a result of not surrounding operators with whitespaces as PEP8 suggests.

`[i**+1 for i in range(3)]` is the same as `[i ** +1 for i in range(3)]` which is the same as `[i ** 1 for i in range(3)]`.

The output of `[i**+1 for i in range(3)]` is `[0, 1, 2]` which is the expected output.

`**+1` is simply `** +1` which is the 1<sup>st</sup> positive power. The `+` is redundant here.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to:
i to the power of 1 i.e +1

[i**+1 for i in range(3)]

NOTE: +1 is not an addition here. it is  the power of i

i.e.

```
   o to the power of +1 = 0;

   1 to the power of +1 = 1;

   2 to the power of +1 = 2;
```

so the answer is: [0, 1, 2]