# Python Iterative Fibonacci

Tags: python, fibonacci

Listen, I know there are a thousand posts about this, and I've spent three hours looking at them all. I know there's a simple reason this code is not working, but I can't figure it out. When it runs, I only want it to return the nth term. I am new to python, and maybe there's some logic I'm not getting. So when I do this:

```
n = int(input("What Fibonacci number would you like to find? "))

def fib(n):
    i = 0
    present = 1
    previous = 0

    while i < n:
        nextterm = present + previous
        present = previous
        previous = nextterm
        i = i + 1
        print nextterm

print(fib(n))
```

I get this:

```
1
1
2
3
5
None
```

When I do this:

```
n = int(input("What Fibonacci number would you like to find? "))

def fib(n):
    i = 0
    present = 1
    previous = 0

    while i < n:
        nextterm = present + previous
        present = previous
        previous = nextterm
        i = i + 1
        return nextterm

print(fib(n))
```

I just get "1"

I have spent so much time on this and I am so confused. Someone please fix me!

Comment: In the first one you never return a value. In the second one you return immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to return the value:

```
n = int(input("What Fibonacci number would you like to find? "))

def fib(n):
    i = 0
    nextterm = 1
    present = 1
    previous = 0

    while i < n:
        nextterm = present + previous
        present = previous
        previous = nextterm
        i = i + 1
        #print nextterm

    return nextterm

print(fib(n))
```

Comment: Note for python 3.x it'd be print(nextterm) instead of 2.7 being print nextterm

Comment: fyi i = i + 1 is the same as i+=1, cool little thing you'll see around

Comment: This is not always true: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python

Comment: haha fair, it's true for ints though

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are not returning anything, so when you `print(fib(n))`, since python doesn't find any `return` statement, it returns `None`, that's the last print you see, the others are the ones inside the loop. In the second case you have the `return` statement inside the `while` loop, so when it performs the first iteration it returns `1`, goes out of the frame and no other iteration is executed, so it just prints `'1'`.

Comment: @OzzyWalsh Not necessarily the answer must contain code, many times it is only necessary to indicate what is missing, please read [answer] :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `return` only returns once, the first time return is done,

Clearer example:

```
 def f():
     return 'good'
     return 'bad'
```

Now:

```
print(f())
```

Returns:

```
'good'
```

in the other hand this is a way to solve it too:

```
n = int(input("What Fibonacci number would you like to find? "))

def fib(n):
    l=[]
    i = 0
    present = 1
    previous = 0

    while i < n:
        nextterm = present + previous
        present = previous
        previous = nextterm
        i = i + 1
        l.append(nextterm)
    return '\n'.join(str(i) for i in l)
print(fib(n))
```

Or `print` with out doing another print:

```
n = int(input("What Fibonacci number would you like to find? "))

def fib(n):
    i = 0
    present = 1
    previous = 0

    while i < n:
        nextterm = present + previous
        present = previous
        previous = nextterm
        i = i + 1
        print(nextterm)
fib(n)
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure that either option is what OP actually wants, but you certainly help understand how to get what they do want, so nice work.

Answer (score -1):

```
def fibonacci():
    num = int(input("How many numbers that generates?:"))
    i = 1
    if num == 0:
        fib = []
    elif num == 1:
        fib = [1]
    elif num == 2:
        fib = [1,1]
    elif num > 2:
        fib = [1,1]
        while i < (num - 1):
            fib.append(fib[i] + fib[i-1])
            i += 1
    return fib
print(fibonacci())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.