# why in python augmented assignment is better than regular assignment?

Tags: python, syntax

why this python code

```py
    a += 1
```

is better than

```
a = a + 1
```

other than the fact that first one is easier to understand and cleaner 
is there any other reason why i should use it like if there are any other difference how python deals with each statement or any performance difference between each or I could use whatever i want .

Comment: Who says that one is better than the other?

Comment: Related question: [When is “i += x” different from “i = i + x” in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simple case you give, there's little difference. Augmented assignment is just considered easier to read because it's a common idiom and expresses a common operation concisely.

But there are situations where it can make a difference. If the place you're incrementing comes from a complex expression or one that has side effects, you don't want to repeat it.

```
a[call_expensive_function()] += 1
vs
a[call_expensive_function()] = a[call_expensive_function()] + 1
```

Also, it's possible for a type to implement `+=` differently from `+`. An example is lists:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = l1
l1 = l1 + [4, 5]
print(l1) # prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(l2) # prints [1, 2, 3]

l3 = [1, 2, 3]
l4 = l3
l3 += [4, 5]
print(l3) # prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(l4) # prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Lists implement `+=` by modifying the list in place (like the `extend()` method), while `+` creates a new list. As you can see from above, this has implications if you have multiple references to the same list.

Comment: Thank you so much but it seems a little bit complicated .can you simplify it to me if you dont mind

Comment: See the related question linked above, it goes into more detail.

Answer (score 0):

`a += 1` is little faster than `a = a+1`.

See the example code.

```
def f(a):
    while a < 10000:
        a += 1
    return a

def g(a):
    while a < 10000:
        a = a + 1
    return a

a = 1
%timeit f(a)
490 µs ± 20.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

a = 1
%timeit g(a)
513 µs ± 34.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Ok so what is the difference between each one .How each one works .where this difference came from