# Python assignment operator differs from non assignment

Tags: python, assignment-operator

I have face this weird behavior I can not find explications about.

MWE:

```
l = [1]
l += {'a': 2}
l
[1, 'a']
l + {'B': 3}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict") to list
```

Basically, when I `+=` python does not raise an error and append the key to the list while when I only compute the `+` I get the expected `TypeError`.

Note: this is Python 3.6.10

Comment: Check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python)

Comment: See https://bugs.python.org/issue9314 - "inconsistent result when concatenating list with iterators". Also note `+=` and so on are called "Augmented assignments" from the PEP introducing them, [PEP 203](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/).

Comment: That is something strange

Comment: I think the bug link by @alkasm has a statment that explains it well. `When a is mutable, a += b updates it in-place, so there is no ambiguity: the type of a cannot change.  When you do a + b, there is no reason to treat a as more deserving than b when selecting the type of the result.`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle that is the exact reasoning. It is not "a bug", it's a mechanism that keeps the interpreter from guessing.

Comment: Yeah i just added it as a comment here to make it clear why the behavior happens as there is quite a lot of info in the link. But yes its not a bug its expected behavior, the comment just helps explain why it works like it does

Comment: @ChrisDoyle that's the case. see my detailed answer below. cheers

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**`l += ...` is actually calling `object.__iadd__(self, other)` and modifies the object `in-place` when `l` is *mutable***

The reason (as @DeepSpace explains in his comment) is that when you do `l += {'a': 2}` the operation updates `l` in place only and only if `l` is mutable. On the other hand, the operation `l + {'a': 2}` is not done in place resulting into `list + dictionary -> TypeError`.

---

(see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__))

---

```
l = [1]
l = l.__iadd__({'a': 2})
l
#[1, 'a']
```

is not the same as `+` that calls `object.__add__(self, other)`

```
l + {'B': 3}
```

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict") to list
```

Comment: This should also explain the reasoning. `l += ...` updates `l` in place, so the type of the result is clear (= the type of `l`). `l + ...` is ambiguous because it is not in place, so the type of the resulting new object is not clear (should it be the type of `l` or should it be the type of `...`?)

Comment: of course! I added this to my answer. The `l += ...` operates **in-place**

Comment: @seralouk, do you mind sharing which tool you used to found out which function was invoked ? Inspect, pdb etc ?

Comment: the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__ and some programming knowledge e.g. dictionary are mutables.

Comment: @DeepSpace the reasoning makes sense, but `__iadd__` is not guaranteed to return the same object. See `number += 2`. Also, from docs: These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self)

Comment: @CapiEtheriel It's not about returning the same object, but about returning the same **type**. Also, `int` is not a good example as it is a special case, `a = 1 ; a += 2.0`, now `a` is float. But, `int` is immutable to begin with, so "in-place" has no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

So as the authors say this is not a bug. When you Do `a += b` it is like `b` come to `a`'s house and changing it the way that `a` like it to be. **what the Authors say is when you do `a + b` it cannot be decided which one's style will get prioritized. and no one knows where will the result of `a + b` will go until you execute it. So you can't decide whose style it would be. if it is `a` style it would be `[1, 'a']`'s, and if it is `b` style it would be an error. and therefore it cannot be decided who will get the priority**. So I don't personally agree with that statement. because when you take the call stack `a` is in a higher place than `b`. when there is a expression like `a + b` you first call `a.__add__(self, other)` if `a.__add__` is `NotImplemented` (in this case it is implemented). then you call `a.__radd__(self, other)`. which means call `other.__add__` in this case `b.__add__`.  I am telling this based on the place of the call stack and the python community may have more important reasons to do this.