# When do the Augmented Assignment operations behave as in-place operations and when do not?

Tags: python, in-place, augmented-assignment

I've always known that Python augmented operations always perform in-place operations. But seems like it's not true for every case. When I apply Augmented operations on `integers`, it's not in place.

```py
    var1 = 1234
    print(id(var1))
    var1 = var1 + 4321
    print(id(var1))

    print()

    var2 = 5678
    print(id(var2))
    var2 += 8765
    print(id(var2))
```

Output:

```
140272195234704
140272195234928

140272195234736
140272195234896
```

But when I apply it on lists, it's in place.

```py
    var1 = [1, 2]
    print(id(var1))
    var1 = var1 + [3]
    print(id(var1))

    print()

    var2 = [5, 6]
    print(id(var2))
    var2 += [7]
    print(id(var2))
```

Output:

```
140461597772992
140461597413184

140461597412480
140461597412480
```

**My question** is, when does it behave as an in-place operation and when does it not? **And why?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is "i += x" different from "i = i + x" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

When you run `var1 = var1 + [3]`, Python first performs the operation on the right, and then assigns it to the variable on the left.  It creates a completely new list with the results of the value on the right, and then then assigns it to the left.  It makes sense that the old list and the new list are different.  In fact, if you ran:

```
var1 = [1, 2]
var2 = var1
var1 = var1 + [3]
```

That `var2` will have the same id as `var1` after the second instruction, and that `var2` will continue to have that same id after the third instruction, while the id of `var` changes.

On the other hand, `var2 += [7]` is an indication that it is okay to reuse the same space.  And += on lists, in most cases, does reuse the same space.

Comment: @HeapOverflow.  What's a better way to say that?  Writing "list.__add__ isn't mutating while list.__iadd__ is mutating" is technically the right answer, but I think the important message is getting lost in technical jargon."

Comment: Oops.  I did mean `extend`.  Are they really not using the same code in the case of a list on either side?

Comment: Editing to include your comments.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

With integers, you're replacing one integer with another in both cases because integers are immutable.  Since in both cases, you're talking about a new object getting assigned to the variable, the `id` of what the variable is pointing to changes in both cases.

In the first list case, you're effectively doing the same thing, replacing one list with another because that's what the `+` operator does...it combines its two operand lists and returns a new list.

But in the `+=` case, you're not changing which list `var2` is pointing to, but rather just manipulating the list that it is pointing to.  Lists are mutable objects that can be modified.  The `+=` operator acts like the list's `extend` method, appending the items in the supplied list onto the existing list.  Because the list that `var2` is pointing to doesn't change, the id doesn't change either.

Comment: Oops.  I did mean `extend`.  Are they really not using the same code in the case of a list on either side?

Comment: It's a shorthand for using the `__iadd__` method if that exists or using the `__add__` method otherwise. And for lists, I believe `__iadd__` *ends up* somewhere in the C code using the same code as `extend`.