# python list behaving differently when used for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

code 1

```
display = []
for _ in range(2):
    display += "_"

print(display)
```

concole output = [" _ ", " _ "]

---

code 2

```
dis = []
dis = dis + "_"

print(dis)
```

output on the console: can only concatenate a string to list

In the first code, I don't understand how concatenation yields the output results. But in the second code when the same thing is performed with no loop it gives the error as mentioned above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is "i += x" different from "i = i + x" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
a = a + b
```

and

```
a += b
```

are **not** equivalent in the general case in Python.
In particular, the mutable types implement the `+=` operation as a mutation (the type of `a` won't change) while `+` will always create a new object (this has greater restrictions wrt the compatibility of the types of the two operands because a decision needs to be made what type the result should be). For lists

```
lst += x
```

corresponds to

```
lst.extend(x)
```

where `extend` can take as an argument any iterable (including strings).
This becomes clearer if you try it with a longer string:

```
lst = []
lst += "abc"
lst
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score -1):

You used `display += "_"` in first code. In second code, you used `dis = dis + "_"`.
If you used `display = display + "_"` in first code, you will get the same error. Use `dis += "_"` in second code.