# What is logic behind runtime of programs?

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime

**Why do just writing the code in different order or style, changes the overall runtime?**

For eg:

> Why is `result += "1"` is more faster than `result = "1" + result` ?

#### More detailed example:

After writing a successful program for this Leetcode problem - [Add Binary](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-binary/)

here I have 2 code snippets **both SAME, but a very subtle difference**.

**CODE 1**

```py
def addBinary(a, b):
    max_len = max(len(a), len(b))
    a = a.zfill(max_len)
    b = b.zfill(max_len)

    result = ""
    carry = 0

    for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
        x = int(a[i])
        y = int(b[i])

        _sum = x + y + carry

        if _sum == 3:
            result += "1"
            carry = 1
        elif _sum == 2:
            result += "0"
            carry = 1
        elif _sum == 1:
            result += "1"
            carry = 0
        else:
            result += "0"
            carry = 0

    if carry == 1:
        result += "1"

    return result[::-1]
```

**CODE 2**

```py
def addBinary(a, b):
    max_len = max(len(a), len(b))
    a = a.zfill(max_len)
    b = b.zfill(max_len)

    result = ""
    carry = 0

    for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
        x = int(a[i])
        y = int(b[i])

        _sum = x + y + carry

        if _sum == 3:
            result = "1" + result
            carry = 1
        elif _sum == 2:
            result = "0" + result
            carry = 1
        elif _sum == 1:
            result = "1" + result
            carry = 0
        else:
            result = "0" + result
            carry = 0

    if carry == 1:
        result += "1"

    return result
```

The runtime for **CODE 1** is `16 ms`, and the runtime for **CODE 2** is `47 ms`. Why?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python) question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding characters to the end is optimised internally to reuse the same string (array of characters) in memory. Adding at the beginning requires creating a new string, with the position of each character shifted.

Comment: hmm, that explains. very silly to ask but... are there any resources/places where we can learn these CORE basics of programming

Comment: @VaibhavShukla this is an obscure CPython implementation detail, not a core basic. Something similar is how `list.append` is faster than `list.insert(0, ...)`, although a `deque` is able to have similar performance on both ends. If you want to learn more about this, look into data structures and algorithms.