# Int can be incremented by a double value

Tags: java, casting, floating-point, int, double

This code seems to work in Java, violating everything I thought I knew about the language:

```
int x = 0;
x += 7.4;
```

x now has the value 7. Of course, one can't just write **int x = 7.4**, so this behavior seems strange and inconsistent to me.

Why did the developers of Java choose such a behavior?

The question that mine was marked as a duplicate of was actually answering the "what happens" part, but not my main question: what the rationale is.

Comment: because `+=` does an implicit cast to `int`, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456462/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java)

Comment: Thank you. That's answered the "what is happening" part. I have clarified my question.

Comment: Try `char ch = '0'; ch *= 1.1; assert ch == '4';`

Comment: This come from `C` and possibly an older language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java += operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operators for numbers do all kinds of casting which in this case converts the 7.4 double to a 7 int by rounding it.

What you have here is a [Compound Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

So what really gets executed is

```
x= (int)(x + 7.4)
```

Since x is an int and 7.4 x gets converted to double vs a [Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) so you get 7.4 as an intermediate result.

The result (a double) is then cast and therefore subject to a [Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) which rounds it to 7

Regarding the new question: Why was it done this way?

Well you can argue long if implicit conversions are a good or bad thing. Java went some kind of middle road with some conversions between primitives, their boxed types and Strings.

The += operator then has a rather simple and straight forward semantics. It really only looks strange if you consider it an *increment by* operator, instead of what it really is: a shorthand for a combination of operator and assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime back only i read about it
It will be actually 
X= (int)(x + 7.4)

Answer (score 1):

No. it's not inconsistent. It round-to-nearest mode.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

> A widening conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long value to double, may result in loss of precision - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode (§4.2.4).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion x = 7 due to basic conversion