# How to store a result of and array and evaluate a sum

Tags: java

I have an array like this.

```
int p[] = new int[n];
```

which is actually like this.

```
//p[2,3,4,5,6];
```

Now I am multiplying each elemnt by 10 and want to store that value and letter wamt sum of that.
my for loop.

```
int res ;
for(int i=0; i<n ;i++){
    res = p[i]* 10;
}
```

Now my question is in second iteration result is loosing the previous hold value. how to fix that.

Comment: If `res` is the sum, shouldn't the assignment be `res += p[i]* 10;` (`res = res + p[i]* 10;`)

Comment: `res += p[i]* 10;` instead of `res = p[i]* 10;`. Otherwise `res` is only going to hold the value in the current iteration since res can only store one int at a time. [Check out this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456462/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java/7456548)

Comment: If you want to store that value back, then it is like p[i] = p[i]*10; res += p[i];

Answer (score 1):

With each iteration your `res` variable is being overwritten with a new value.
Try this:

```
int res=0; //initializing this to 0 is important!
for(int i=0; i<n ;i++){
    res += p[i]* 10; //increment res by the 10 times p[i] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well there are two ways:
way 1: make an array of results and have each block of the array save all the results, but this way is only for a case in which you need to use the single values later.
way 2: in this case the way you should go with is to write this line of code inside the for loop:

```
res += p[i]* 10;
```

and return or print (whatever you need) res

Answer (score 1):

```
int res=0; //initializing res with 0
for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
res=res+p[j]*10;
}
```