# In a while loop, how do you add a variable from the past loop to the same variable in the current loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

So i am really new to Java, only started programming a couple of months ago for a class. I am completely and utterly stuck on this project. [This is the project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kjI2.png)

And this is my code so far.

```
double mile;
double gas;
int week;
double mpg;
double totalMile; 
double totalGas;




week = 0;
gas = 0;
mile = 0;
totalMile = 0;
totalGas = 0;

Scanner reply = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter the amount of miles.");
mile = reply.nextDouble();



while(mile != -99)
{
    week++;



    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of gas (in gallons) purchased for this week.");
    gas = reply.nextDouble();
    mpg = mile / gas;



    System.out.println("Week: "+week+"");
    System.out.println("Miles: "+mile+" Vacation Miles Traveled: "+totalMile+"");
    System.out.println("Gallons: "+gas+" Vacation Gallons Purchased: "+totalGas+"");        
    System.out.println("MPG: "+mpg+"");

    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of miles.");
    mile = reply.nextDouble();


}
```

The only part I am REALLY stuck on is how to get the "Vacation Miles/Gas" values, I don't know how to add up a total of the same variable while in a while loop.

Comment: You have one while loop and that's it, add variable from which other loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to keep a running total, try `totalmile += reply.nextDouble();`

[What this does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456462/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java/7456548) is totalmile = totalmile + reply.nextDouble();

Comment: It would be `totalmile += mile;` that should be added, judging by the rest of the loop.

Comment: @KenY-N Dohh, thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to keep track of all the miles you've driven since the very beginning?

Why not just use your total miles or total gallons variables in the while loop?

```
totalmile += mile
totalgas += gas
```

You might also want to move your

```
System.out.println("Please enter the amount of miles.");
mile = reply.nextDouble();
```

So your code looks like:

```
week++;

System.out.println("Please enter the amount of gas (in gallons) purchased for this week.");
gas = reply.nextDouble();
mpg = mile / gas;

System.out.println("Please enter the amount of miles.");
mile = reply.nextDouble();

totalgas += gas
totalmiles += mile

System.out.println("Week: "+week+"");
System.out.println("Miles: "+mile+" Vacation Miles Traveled: "+totalmile+"");
System.out.println("Gallons: "+gas+" Vacation Gallons Purchased: "+totalgas+"");        
System.out.println("MPG: "+mpg+"");
```

So yeah.
Good luck with your programming assignment!