# Java += compiler/jre bug?

Tags: java

I encountered someting unexpected with the java += operator.

Apparently, this compiles:

```
int a = 0;
a += 3/2.0;
System.out.println(a);  // outputs "1"
```

While, this doesn't

```
int a = 0;
a = a + (3/2.0);   // eclipse compiler error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int"
System.out.println(a);
```

Is this expected behaviour? I find it strange that the += operator does not report a "Type mismatch", because it is an 'add and assign' operator, where you add a double, which gives a double result, and is then assigned to an int variable. Instead it silently casts (and truncates) the result.

Comment: Have a look @ this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8710685/2024761) & this [too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/608728/2024761).

Comment: I should Cut&Paste the answer from there, so my rep goes skywards ;-)

Comment: if gosling read this question then he would do FACEPALMS :P  , he call it a bug in java , lol

Answer (score 3):

This is the way += has worked from `C`.  It's "feature" not a bug

See [Java's +=, -=, *=, /= compound assignment operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator)

BTW You can try this

```
char ch = '0';
ch *= 1.1; // ch = '4'
```

Also see a post of mine http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2012/11/java-and-implicit-casting.html

Comment: C does the narrowing conversion in the assignment without complaint, so that's not C legacy, that's a compromise made when making Java stricter than C and C++.

Comment: The original [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8710747/2024761)!

Comment: @R.J Well spotted, but memory isn't so good some times ;)

Comment: When java designers see simple `int d=1.3` as a compiler error instead of just a warning, how justified is it to make `int a+=3/2.0` compilable when it's equivalent sin?

Comment: @pinkpanther I think it's an inconsistency which came about becuase they made assignment more strict but perhaps assumed that if you use an assignment operator you knew what you were doing.  Given C allows implicit casts, they may not have thought it such a problem.

Answer (score 2):

`int a = a + (3/2.0);`    doesn't compile since:

- `int` + `double` leads to a `double`
- `a` is referenced as an `int`
- cast from `double` to int missing

`int a += 3/2.0;`  compiles since:

- `int` + `double` leads to a double
- `a` is referenced as an `int`
- `double` is castable to an `int` and luckily, compiler adds an implicit cast similar to:

  `int a = (int)(a+ 3/2.0);`. This is due to the special `op=` notation that is interpreted more cleverly from compiler than the basic assignment operator: `=`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug , its a implicit conversion happened.

for eg.

```
Byte b=3;

b+=5;  //compiles

b=b+5; //doesnt compiles
```

Here what happens is

```
a=a+3/2.0;   // 3/2.0 produces double , it add int to double but cant convert it implicitly to int.

a += 3/2.0;  // here implicit conversion after addition of a to 3/2.0 happends from double to int
```